# Inspect the names/values of arguments in the definition/execution of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, arguments, inspection

I'm looking to do the equivalent of Python's `inspect.getargspec()` in Javascript.

I do know that you can get the `arguments` list from a Javascript function, but what I'm really looking for is the *names* of the arguments from the originally defined function.

If this is in fact impossible, I'm going to have to 'brute-force' it by getting the string of the function, i.e. `myFunc.toString()` and then parsing out the `...` inside of `function myFunc(...)`.  Does anyone know how to do this parsing in a general way?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While I can't see any good reason for this,

```
var reg = /\(([\s\S]*?)\)/;
var params = reg.exec(func);
if (params) 
     var param_names = params[1].split(',');
```

assuming `func` is the name of your function

Comment: Nice, thanks!  I do have some good reasons for this :) ...and they are mostly related to wanting to replicate some working Python code that uses `inspect.getargspec()`, in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm still wondering though if this is the only way of doing such an inspection... there is no more elegant way?

Comment: nothing that I know of, no. It's certainly not a common way to do things in JavaScript.

Comment: Note that it doesn't play well at all with minifiers that change variable names, so you should be really carefull when using this kind of hacks.

Comment: @Grégoire: Honestly, it isn't a practice I'd advocate at all, but the OP question was fairly clear and this is the only way of getting those argument names. If a minifier is used, all you'll get is the new minified names, which, hopefully, should still be enough.

Comment: You would need to know parameter names or function names, etc .. if you were building a tool that manipulates the code itself, such as a debugger, or dynamic code generators. The mimifier problem might then be handled using source maps.

Comment: The only reason not to go that route is if you anticipate the developer might include comments in the parameter definitions. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1007981#9924463) includes handling for this possibility.

Comment: Can't your regexp just be simplified to `/\((.*)\)/` ?

Answer (score 5):

The following function will return an array of parameter names of any function passed in.

```
function getParamNames(func) {
    var funStr = func.toString();
    return funStr.slice(funStr.indexOf('(')+1, funStr.indexOf(')')).match(/([^\s,]+)/g);
}
```

Example usage:

```
getParamNames(getParamNames) // returns ['func']
getParamNames(function (a,b,c,d){}) // returns ['a','b','c','d']
```

Answer (score 4):

here a small nodejs module for that.

https://github.com/kilianc/node-introspect

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that uses higher order functions. The only thing I don't like about it is that you have to specify parameters as members of an array. But at least they only have to be specified once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var withNamedParams = function(params, lambda) {
    return function() {
        var named = {};
        var max   = arguments.length;

        for (var i=0; i<max; i++) {
            named[params[i]] = arguments[i];
        }

        return lambda(named);
    };
};

var foo = withNamedParams(["a", "b", "c"], function(params) {
    for (var param in params) {
        alert(param + ": " + params[param]);
    }
});

foo(1, 2, 3);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sightly improved version of Jonathan Fingland's answer:

```
// Utility function to extract arg name-value pairs
function getArgs(args) {
    var argsObj = {};

    var argList = /\(([^)]*)/.exec(args.callee)[1];
    var argCnt = 0;
    var tokens;

    while (tokens = /\s*([^,]+)/g.exec(argList)) {
        argsObj[tokens[1]] = args[argCnt++];
    }

    return argsObj;
}

// Test subject
function add(number1, number2) {
    var args = getArgs(arguments);
    alert(args.toSource()); // ({number1:3,number2:4})
}

// Invoke test subject
add(3, 4);
```

Note: This only works on browsers that support `arguments.callee`.

(Also posted at [How to get function parameter names/values dynamically from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically-from-javascript/1009013#1009013))

Comment: This is not good because you have to run the function to get its arguments. The question was to get arguments from the definition.