# Getting functions content with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the functions from an input string by using regular expressions.

So far, I managed to get the [JavaScript kind of function declarations](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/different-ways-of-defining-functions-in-javascript-this-is-madness/) with the following regex:

```
/(\b(f|F)unction(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s*\{)/g
```

Which when applied like this, will return me whole declaration on the first index:

```
var re = /(\b(f|F)unction(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s*\{)/g;

while ((m = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
    //m[0] contains the function declaration
    declarations.push(m[0]);
}
```

Now, I would like to get in the returned match, the whole content of each of the functions so I can work with it later on (removed it, wrap it...)

I haven't managed to find a regext to do so, so far, I got this:

```
(\b(f|F)unction(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s*\{)(.*?|\n)*\}
```

But of course, it catches the first closing bracket `}` instead of the one at the end of each of the functions.

Any idea of how to get the closing `}` of each function?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Perhaps there's a better way to achieve your end goal?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952870/regular-expression-to-get-parameter-list-from-function-definition

Comment: This is impossible to do with regex alone since regular expressions contain no capacity for counting, which is what you would need to match brackets.

Comment: @JamesMontagne the why is not relevant here I'm afraid.

Comment: @carlosa. not the same...

Comment: You should use a parser like http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/parser

Comment: @Kos thanks! That may be the way!

Comment: The why is always relevant, because it helps avoid wasting time on [XY-Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any idea of how to get the closing } of each function?

This will be very hard with a regex. Because the function body can include any number of possibly nested brace pairs. And then consider strings containing unmatched braces in the function body.

To parse a non-[regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) you need something more powerful than regular expressions: a parser for that language.

(Some regex variants have some ability to matched paired characters, but firstly JavaScript's regex engine isn't one; and secondly then there are those strings….)

Comment: Agree, but the string trap is not so difficult to avoid, on the other hand a function that contains a regex non enclosed in a string as in javascript...