# Parse formula name and arguments with regex

Tags: regex

The objective of [this Regex](https://regex101.com/r/pX0nQ6/3) `(\w*)\s*\([(\w*),]*\)` is to get a function name and its arguments.

For example, given `f1 (11,22,33)`

the Regex should capture four elements:

`f1`
`11`
`22`
`33`

What's wrong with this regex?

Comment: You seem to be capturing whitespace for the arguments. It also appears that this regex can capture just as list of commas as argument, since `(\w*)` would indicate even zero-length sequences (of whitespace). And the last argument for the function here requires to be followed by a comma; you may need to add a separate group for the last argument.

Comment: you can't use special characters within `[]`. Also, don't use regex for this

Comment: I doubt you can use grouping parenthesis inside a character set.

Comment: @hop: you can use special characters, but you likely can't use grouping. the parentheses just take a different value than intended, but the `\w` (a special character) does work.

Comment: @Evert: yeah, like splitting hairs will fix this mess.

Comment: I'm new to regex, but this doesn't seem a complex problem to solve, why is it? @hop it would be good if you made a recommendation instead of just giving negative comments

Comment: @ps0604: if you are new to regex, how do you know it's not a complex problem? here is a recommendation: don't use regex. seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `split` Here is an example in `javascript`

```
var ar = str.match(/\((.*?)\)/);
if (ar) {
  var result = ar[0].split(",");
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13953005/1827594

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me closer, see https://regex101.com/r/pX0nQ6/7

Answer (score 0):

Some things are hard for regexes :-)

As the commenters above are saying, '*' can be too lax. It means zero or more. So `foo(,,)` also matches. Not so good.

```
(\w+)\s*\((\w+)(?:,\s*(\w+)\s*)*\)
```

That is closer to what you want I think. Let's break that down.

```
\w+   <-- The function name, has to have at least one character
\s*   <-- zero or more whitespace
\(    <-- parens to start the function call
(\w+) <-- at least one parameter
(?:)  <-- this means not to save the matches
,\s*  <-- a comma with optional space
(\w+) <-- another parameter
\s*   <-- followed by optional space
```

This is the result from Python:

```
>>> m = re.match(r'(\w+)\s*\((\w+)(?:,\s*(\w+)\s*)*\)', "foo(a,b,c)")
>>> m.groups()
('foo', 'a', 'c')
```

But, what about something like this:

```
foo(a,b,c
    d,e,f)
```

?? Yeah, it gets hard fast with regexes and you move on to richer parsing tools.

Comment: there's a problem with your regex, see https://regex101.com/r/pX0nQ6/5

Comment: Yeah, the joys of trying to answer a question before heading home.

Comment: you can eliminate any new lines and extra spaces before you run the regex

Comment: Sometimes. Depends on syntax, comments, etc. If they embed comments after each parameter than just collapsing the newlines will not work.