# Check if function expect any data

Tags: javascript

It is possible to check if function expect/need any data?

```
function one(){

}
function two(ineedvar){

}
```

So i have to functions and I would like to check which of them need var between ().

Comment: No, you can't do it *reliably*. But wanting to do this *usually* is a sign of flawed design. What do you need it for?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9924463/1873485

Comment: Don't forget - a function doesn't have to define any parameters to accept them - it can access the `arguments` object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.length` property of the function to see if it takes any argument.

i.e `two.length`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AtJc9/)**

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

But note that function can also take `arguments` without having it define it in the function declaration, so can't rely on that always.

Comment: whoa, I did not know this!

Answer (score 2):

Use `length` property of the `Function` object:

```
one.length /* 0 */
two.length /* 1 */
```