# Regex to capture typed information in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm new to Regex, took some tutorials, having a hard time getting this right.

I'm working on a language support for TypeScript for a text editor, and I need a regex that matches JUST the typing information in a function. For example:

```
function asdf(param1:type1, param2:type2, param3:type3) {...}
```

In that, my regex should match 'type1', 'type2', 'type3' etc.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
\(.+?:(\w).+?\)
```

Breaks down like this:

`\(` look for starting parenthesis

`.+?:` any number of characters up to the colon

`(\w)` capture group: the next word

`.+?` There may be additional words after this

`\)` Close parentheses for the end of the function parameters.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but like I said I'm new to regex. Currently it captures the entire stuff, from beginning parens to closing parens. I need it to match JUST the single words after the colon.

NOTE: I want to make sure it only matches words after colons inside parens, so that it doesn't match object key/data combos, which look similar in Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the regex engine you use?

Comment: This is going to be for the Atom text editor, so I assume it's Javascript in the end since it is built using web technologies.

Comment: A more general way to ask this question is: how do I include characters in a regex query without having them be PART of the match? If I want words after a colon (:) for example, can I include the colon without matching the colon somehow?

Comment: The javascript regex engine is not really able to do something like that. you can cheat with this kind of pattern: `[^:)]+(?=,[^()]*\)|\))` but note that this doesn't check the opening parenthesis.

Comment: with a more advanced regex engine (perl/php/java/.net) you can write: `(?:\G(?!\A), |\()[^:]+:\K[^,)]+(?=[^()]*\))` that is more robust.

Comment: Regex is not really powerful enough to parse something like this. TypeScript is open source and has a parser that is guaranteed to produce the correct result; why not use that?

Comment: I'm trying to update and contribute to a Typescript Language package for Atom. The sepcs say that you include regex for what should be matched, then specify which classes to attach to the match. I believe I can only use raw regex, which is why I'm looking for a regex solution.

Comment: But perhaps I'm misunderstanding and there's still a better way? I'd love to hear it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try thus

```
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;
function getParamNames(func) {
  var fnStr = func.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '')
  var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES)
  if(result === null)
     result = []
  for(i=0; i< result.length; i++)
      result[i]=result[i].split(":")[1];
  return result
}
```

how to use

```
   getParamNames("function asdf(param1:type1, param2:type2, param3:type3) {...}");
```

reference

[How to get function parameter names/values dynamically from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically-from-javascript)