# How does Angular know the names of your constructor arguments?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function

Quoted from the Angular tutorial:

> To use a service in Angular, you simply declare the names of the
>   dependencies you need as arguments to the controller's constructor
>   function, as follows:
>
> ```
> phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {...}
> ```

It seems that the `controller` method is checking which services you've requested by looking at the argument names, such as `$scope` and `$http`. But that seems so crude. Is it actually just converting the function to a string and slicing it, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically-from-javascript)? Or is there some cleverer behind-the-scenes action going on?

How does it know which services your controller requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Angular just looks at the argument names. This causes problems with minification because minification could convert `function ($scope, $http)` to `function (a, b)` and then angular won't know which is what.

Instead you should use the long syntax:

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {...}
```

In terms of how it works. Angularjs makes clever use of the fact that every object in JavaScript has a toString function to parse and extract the names of the parameters before deciding what arguments to call your controller function with. This page has some more detail about it: http://www.alexrothenberg.com/2013/02/11/the-magic-behind-angularjs-dependency-injection.html

Comment: You don't need to use the long syntax. It's ugly and hard to maintain. See ngannotate as a tool to inject the long syntax when building the js. https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

Comment: @PeterAshwell That's correct, that you don't need to if using ng-annotate. I don't agree that it's ugly. It's slightly harder to maintain but not much.