# Annotate javascript function parameters?

Tags: javascript, reflection, annotate

Is it possible to annotate JavaScript function parameters as can be done with *attributes* in C#?

**Example (C#)**:

```
public void DoSomething([RequiredAction(Action="some_action")] Client client) {
    // ...
}
```

The aim is - given a function - use reflection to inspect for instance the "type" of the parameters and perform the necessary conversions before calling it. *JavaScript* is indeed dynamically typed, but one could for instance want to use annotations to define the "type" of instances, a specific function expects (for instance, `param` should be an integer, or an array).

**EDIT**: The type aspect is only one possible use of an annotation. One could for instance also specify one must first run a specific function on that attribute or aspects like the maximum allowed length of an array.

One can of course use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924463/67579) and annotate the parameters by using specific parameter prefixes. For instance the [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) where `sParam` would identify the parameter should be a string. But that's not really convenient nor that extensible since it requires to specify names. Is there a more generic way to achieve this?

Comment: JavaScript function parameters (and variables in general) don't have a type. (JavaScript *values* have a type, but a given variable can refer to different types.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I know that, but that doesn't imply the *algorithm* doesn't expect a certain type. Even in extremely dynamically typed languages like `bash` shell, one must make contracts about what to pass and what not. An example of a "type" could be that the method only accepts positive numbers. Thus they don't have to map on any predefined type system.

Comment: Basically no, the best you can do is use comments other than the suggestions that you have already made, i.e. the notation.

Comment: Have you looked into `Typescript`? It adds optional type annotations and compile-time type checking.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: that's an improvement. But the types should also be checked at runtime (and not only types) such that if a function is passed to another function. The second can inspect the first and make a decision based on that...

Answer (score 8):

I like to use [JSDOC](https://jsdoc.app/), these are not checked at runtime but can be checked in certain editors ([komodo edit](http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/) for example) and stand alone applications (I think [Google closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/) is one). An example.

```
/**
 * @namespace {Object} myObject
 */
var myObject = {};

/**
 * This returns true if the operand inputArg is a String.
 * @memberof myObject
 * @name something
 * @function
 * @param {*} inputArg
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
myObject.something = function (inputArg) {
    return type inputArg === 'string';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to require the argument type, rather than comment on its type, then the closest you can do is to make a function to simulate it.

```
function assertType(val, type) {
    if (typeof val != 'object') {
      if (typeof val != type.name.replace(/^./, function(f){return f.toLowerCase();}))
        throw new Error("`" + val + "` is not of the data type `" + type.name + "`.");
    }
    else if (!(val instanceof type)) {
        throw new Error("`" + val + "` is not of the data type `" + type.name + "`.");
    }
}

function double(num) {
    assertType(num, Number);
    return num * 2;
}

console.log(double("malformed"));
/*
Error: `malformed` is not of the data type `number`.
    at assertType:14:9
    at double:18:2
    at eval:21:13
    at eval
*/
```

However, there isn't way to do this in the function declaration itself.