# Differentiate between nodejs request and response

Tags: node.js

There is a generic structure of `nodejs` callback functions :

```
function(req,res){
  //handle callback
}
```

I just want, callback should work correctly even if sometimes i write in mistake `(res, req)`

Given mixture of `req` or `res`, how do i find which one is actually request and which one is response.

Comment: According to the API, `req` goes before `res`, regardless of how you really name them. You should just avoid swapping in your functions.

Answer (score 4):

`req` is an [`IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage) object and `res` is a [`ServerResponse`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object.

So check for unique properties on each, for example if the particular object has a `writeHead()` function, then it's the response object.

You *may* also be able to use `instanceof` to check: `res instanceof http.ServerResponse`.

Answer (score 3):

Functions in JavaScript are not programmatically prototyped by parameter names. The `length` property of a function only provides the number of parameters specified in the definition:

```
var fn = function (one,two,three) { return "x"; };
console.log(fn.length); // 3
```

Although there are ways to retrieve these names (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically-from-javascript)), usually procedures simply ignore how you name the parameters of your functions/closures, and instead assume that you are following the proposed API.

For this reason, it remains as the best practice to pay attention to the API and name parameters accordingly. In a Node.js HTTP request listener, the `request` comes always before the `response` (it is [documented](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) and many examples are available). As mentioned by other answers, you can dynamically check whether the request is an `http.IncomingMessage` or whether the response is an `http.ServerResponse`, but it seems to me that you can avoid introducing an overhead just with proper naming.

---

With that said, given the variables `req` and `res`, it is easy to make a check at the top of a function body, like the code below. However, do note that this would only be remedying what can be prevented by just following the API contracts, and as thus I *cannot* recommend it (unless you really want to make functions with a more flexible API).

```
function(res,req) {
  if (req instanceof http.ServerResponse) {
    // wrong order, swap.
    var t = req;
    req = res;
    res = t;
  }
  // handle request
}
```