# Is it possible to change scope of function after new Function()?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

So I have this code:

```
function fn(a){
  var f=(new Function("return a"));
  return f();
}
fn(7)//ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Same problems with local variables:

```
function fn(){
  var a=7;
  var f=new Function("return a");
  return f();
}
fn(7)//ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

I want it to return a but the new function cant see a,
it can only see global a

```
var a=1;
function fn(a){
  var f=(new Function("return a"));
  return f();
}
fn(7)//1
```

With the normal initialization the function can see the argument.

```
function fn(a){
  var f=function(){return a};
  return f();
}
fn(7)//7
```

I need to call the basic constructor in my project and can't use global variables.
I know that i could solve this by giving arguments to the newly created function and call it with that like this:

```
function fn(a){
  var f=(new Function('a',"return a"));
  return f(a);
}
fn(7)//7
```

And also could use some parsing function and some stupidly long method to make incoming arguments reachable like this:

```
function parsargs(funct){
   //some parsing methodes giving back argument name list from funct.toString()
  return "['a','b']";//like this
}


function fn(a,b){
  var arrgstr,retfunc;

  arrgstr="";
  for(var i in arguments)
  {
    if(i<arguments.length-1)
      arrgstr+=arguments[i]+",";
    else
      arrgstr+=arguments[i];
  }
  //return arrgstr;
  retfunc="var f=new Function("+parsargs()+",'return b*a');return f("+arrgstr+")";
  return (new Function(retfunc))();
}
fn(7,4)//28
```

But there must be an easier way which reaches local variables and functions  as well...
Any suggestions?

PS:
 i am trying to replace eval() in the project

Here is a simplified version of my original problem:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h6dv68Lu/)

**The answer is NO**...

Comment: Do you want it to be compatible with ES6 and strict mode (i.e. not using arguments.callee) ? Do you want to be able to freely name the argument of fn ?

Comment: I have the strong feeling this is a XY question. What's the real goal ?

Comment: arguments.callee is not an option for me...

Comment: `PS: i am trying to replace eval() in the project` => You seem to be trying to replace `eval` with a more complex solution with the same problems. It only makes it worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `call` your new Function with a context that references the local variables that you need:

```
function f(a) {
  var b = 30;
  return new Function("return this.a + this.b").call({ a: a, b: b })
}

f(10) // 40
```

Comment: Not directly answers the question but your previous answer pointed out the basic problem i have with that matter, so i ll accept this answer because you gave me a work around that i can use.

Answer (score 2):

Your exact question isn't clear but, supposing you can use `arguments.callee` (i.e. non strict mode) and that you want to be able to have any arguments name in `fn`, you "may" do this:

```
function fn(a,b){
  var strargs = arguments.callee.toString().match(/\(([^\)]*)\)/)[1];
  return (new Function(strargs.split(","),"return a+b")).apply(null,arguments);
}
console.log(fn(7, 3)) // 10
```

But I have a strong feeling this is a XY question and that we could have given a more useful answer knowing the real original problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i added a fiddle where is a simplified version of the original code. I want to replace the eval() s to new Function(). Would you please look at it? You will might have some suggestions.

Comment: @szinter You could  parse the string that you're currently evaling but the only clean and maintanable solution would be define a structural model of what you're currently evaling and pass an object instead of a free code. This model would of course totally depend of your application logic and realm.

Comment: This solution replaces a nightmarishly long if else based code(8 KLOC~)

Comment: @szinter Modelling complex constraints is always a complex task (and if it's if/else based it's obviously a bad model). But it's better than not modelling them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this isn't working as easy as you would like is that JavaScript doesn't blindly put variables in a scope. Instead, it parses the function body (as good as it can) and determines which variables the code will need. It will then look up the variables in the outer scopes, create references for them and attach those references to the new function. That's what keeps variables from the outer scope accessible inside of the function when it eventually will be executed.

You want to build a function from a string body. JavaScript can't tell which variables the body will use and hence, it won't make those variables available.

To make it work for function arguments, use `apply():`:

```
function fn(a){
   var argref = arguments; // create reference to the arguments of fn() and hence to a or any other arguments
   var func = new Function("return arguments[0]");
   var wrapper = function() {
      return func.apply(null, argref);
   };
   return wrapper;
}
```

Note that you still can't reference arguments by name since the code never specifies what the names of the arguments of `func` are - JavaScript can't magically read you mind and do what you want. If you want to access the arguments by name, you need to tell the interpreter the names.

This question has some code how to determine the names from a function reference: [How to get function parameter names/values dynamically from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically-from-javascript)

I don't see a way to make local variables available without passing them to `fn()` as arguments. Even if you used them inside of `fn()`, they would be out of scope when `func()` is eventually executed.

A simple solution would be to pass an object to `fn()`:

```
function fn(conf) {
   var func = new Function('conf', "return conf.a");
   var wrapper = function(conf) {
       return func.apply(null, conf);
   };
   return wrapper;
}

fn({a:7});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i added a fiddle where is a simplified version of the original code. I want to replace the eval() s to new Function().
Would you please look at it? You will might have some suggestion.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace `eval()`?

Answer (score 1):

`new Function` [doesn't create a closure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), but `eval` does.

Here's a low-tech way to build a function with an arbitrary evaluated body and access to the calling scope:

```
function f(a) {
  return eval("(function() { return a })")()
}

f(10) // 10
```

Comment: yeah i forgot to tell that i am trying to replacing eval() in the project sry

Comment: What's the reason for removing it?

Comment: Do you know that `new Function` will be faster? [this JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-new-function-constructor/9) suggests `eval` is faster (at least in the simple test cases).

Comment: I found this perf: http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-new-function  witch suggested new Function will be faster

Comment: yes i can see bigger numbers next to new Function in FF but lover numbers in chrome. You are kind of right but in the same time not :)

Comment: Interesting, and apologies for jumping to a conclusion :)