# Is it possible to log variable name in JavaScript?

Tags: string, variables, console.log

Is it possible to log variable name (not value) in JavaScript?

```
var max_value = 4;
console.log(max_value); // should log "max_value" as a string
```

UPDATE: I need a testing function that should be able to log any variable name (passed as an argument) as a string, not just this one variable.

Comment: `console.log("max_value");` ?

Comment: why do you need this? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution that can help you. I grabbed this function from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically-from-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top), which is able to get the name of the function parameters:

```
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;
function getParamNames(func) {
  var fnStr = func.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES);
  if(result === null)
     result = [];
  return result;
}
```

then all you need to do now, is to use the name of your variable as a parameter of an anonymous function and pass all the function as argument of the getParamNames :

```
variablesNames = getParamNames(function (max_value, min_value) {});
```

This will return an array like this :

```
result => ["max_value", "min_value"];
```

Let's make it practical, first change the name of the getParamNames function to something easy and small like this :

```
function __ (func) {
   // code here  ...
}
```

second thing, instead of returning an array, just return the first element of the array, change this :

```
return result;
```

to this :

```
return result.shift();
```

now, you can get the name of your variable like this :

```
__(function( max_value ){});
```