# How to distinguish between a getter and a setter and a plain property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I programmatically identify getter and setter properties in ES5?

```
var o, descriptor, descriptorGetter, descriptorSetter;

o = { 
  foo: 'foo',
  get bar() {
    return 'bar';
  },
  set bam(value) {
    this._bam = value;
  },
};

descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'foo');
descriptorGetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'bar');
descriptorSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'bam');

console.log(JSON.stringify(descriptor));
console.log(JSON.stringify(descriptorGetter));
console.log(JSON.stringify(descriptorSetter));
```

Prints:

```
{"value":"foo","writable":true,"enumerable":true,"configurable":true}
{"enumerable":true,"configurable":true}
{"enumerable":true,"configurable":true}
```

Comment: `!({a:1}).__lookupGetter__("a")` will be false since `a` not a getter. If it was the function would coerce into true, so the end result is like hasOwnProperty(), but for getters...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are `stringify`ing, you will lose all the `undefined` and the Function objects. Instead, you can check if the returned property descriptor object has a non-undefined `get` or `set` properties and decide like this

1. If the property descriptor has a `value` property, it is a normal data property.
2. If the property descriptor has `get` and `set` properties, and both have functions as values, then it is an accessor property.
3. If the property descriptor has `get`'s value as a function, then it is a getter property.
4. Otherwise, a setter property.

---

Since `value` is there, it is a normal data property:

```
descriptor.hasOwnProperty('value');
// true
```

Here, `value` is not there, but `get` property is a function. So a getter property:

```
descriptorGetter.hasOwnProperty('value');
// false
typeof descriptorGetter.get === 'function';
// true
typeof descriptorGetter.set === 'function';
// false
```

Here also, `value` is not there, but `set` property is a function. So a setter property:

```
descriptorSetter.hasOwnProperty('value');
// false
typeof descriptorSetter.get === 'function';
// false
typeof descriptorSetter.set === 'function';
// true
```

---

Apart from that, if you had an accessor property, like this

```
var o = {
    get cabbage() {
        return 'cabbage';
    },
    set cabbage(value) {
        this._cabbage = value;
    },
};

descriptorCabbage = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'cabbage');

console.log(descriptorCabbage.hasOwnProperty('value'));
// false
console.log(typeof descriptorCabbage.get === 'function');
// true
console.log(typeof descriptorCabbage.set === 'function');
// true
```

---

You can write this as a function, like this

```
function getTypeOfProperty(object, property) {
    var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, property);

    if (desc.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
        return 'data';
    }

    if (typeof desc.get === 'function' && typeof desc.set === 'function') {
        return 'accessor';
    }

    return typeof desc.get === 'function' ? 'getter' : 'setter';
}

console.log(getTypeOfProperty(o, 'foo'));
// data
console.log(getTypeOfProperty(o, 'bar'));
// getter
console.log(getTypeOfProperty(o, 'bam'));
// setter
console.log(getTypeOfProperty(o, 'cabbage'));
// accessor
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `JSON.stringify`, which is what makes this difficult to see. Getter and setters are functions, which can't be serialized as JSON, so they don't show up. I'd simply do this:

```
if ('value' in descriptor){
  // The descriptor is for a data property.
  // Read 'descriptor.value' in here.
} else {
  // The descriptor is for an accessor property.
  // Read 'descriptor.get' and 'descriptor.set' in here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/4ndk64sv/)***

According to **[Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)**

> A property descriptor is a record with some of the following attributes:
>
> - *get*
>   A function which serves as a getter for the property, or undefined if there is no getter (accessor descriptors only).
> - *set*
>   A function which serves as a setter for the property, or undefined if there is no setter (accessor descriptors only).

As a result, if you use this on a property which is a get or set function then it should have those be defined (as opposed to undefined). This can be seen with

```
console.log(descriptorGetter.get);//function bar()
console.log(descriptorSetter.set);//function bam(value)
```

[image]

From your shown code where `.get` shows the function `bar()` and `.set` shows the function `bam(value)`.

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/7ekf8xtt/)***

A simple way to examine this in a helper function could be

```
function isGet(obj,prop){
 return toString.call(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop).get) == "[object Function]";    
}
function isSet(obj,prop){
 return toString.call(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop).set) == "[object Function]";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the setter should at least receive one parameter and the getter shouldn't use any parametter.

However probably that won't always the case.
To find out how many parameters a function requires you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924463/1437934)

```
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;
function getParamNames(func) {
  var fnStr = func.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES);
  if(result === null)
     result = [];
  return result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
getParamNames(getParamNames) // returns ['func']
getParamNames(function (a,b,c,d){}) // returns ['a','b','c','d']
getParamNames(function (a,/*b,c,*/d){}) // returns ['a','d']
getParamNames(function (){}) // returns []
```