# Determining if a property is a getter or setter (or both) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a convenience method in ES5 to determine whether a property is a getter or setter, or is the following idiomatic?

```
var o = {
  get foo() { return 'foo'; },
  set bar(value) {},
  bam: 'bam',
};

function isGetterOrSetter(o, k) {
  var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, k);
  return !!(descriptor.get || descriptor.set);
}

isGetterOrSetter(o, 'foo'); // true
isGetterOrSetter(o, 'bar'); // true
isGetterOrSetter(o, 'bam'); // false
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: I am asking whether there is a pre-existing API to determine whether a property is a getter or setter. I'll ammend the question.

Comment: How is it different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30742312/1903116) question of yours?

Comment: @thefourtheye I forgot I asked it!

Comment: @BenAston: I took the previous question to mean something different from this one ("how do I do this" vs. "Is there a built-in that does this rather than my code below"). But if you think they're the same, let me know, and I'll delete my answer so you can delete your question.

Comment: Concur with your analysis. Different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no built-in ES5 (or ES6, I don't think) function that reduces it further than in your question.