# javascript: get names of actual arguments passed in a function

Tags: javascript

Can we know the name of actual arguments passed in the function? like

```
func(a,b,c,d);
```

when we call this I want a,b,c,d printed in output. Something like if I define func as

```
function func(e,f,g,h) {
// do something here so that
console.log('something');//prints a,b,c,d as output
}
```

EDIT: Following does not serve the purpose completely but if nothing can be done in javascript related to this question then following can be an answer. See, if anyone can build around this?

```
function func(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),result='';

        for(var i in this){

            if(args.indexOf( this[i])!==-1 ){
                result+=i+',';
                }

        }

    console.log(result);
    }
```

so, if I call like,

```
var a=22, b=46, c=99;
func.call(this,a,b,c);//or func(a,b,c)
```

will print a,b,c but

in following case it will fail:

```
var w=4,a=4, b=4, c=99;
```

then output will be a,b,c,w which is wrong as w is not the argument passed.

See, if anyone can build around this?

Comment: Can you explain, why you need the names?

Comment: @Tushar : I need that because the names also contain some information which I need in my function logic

Comment: Can you give example, I'm sure there'll another way

Comment: @Tushar if i call func(a,b,c,d) then there is one flow if logic in func and if I call it with func(l,m,n,d) then the logic flow in func algorithm changes and accordingly the output will change too

Comment: Then add one more param and use `switch` for logic

Comment: I cannot change the function calls whatever I can modify will be inside func body. That func body can be modified in all possible ways

Comment: @ShishirArora you cant get the name of a variable based on its value.

Comment: @Hackto: We have an 'arguments' variable available which has information about what is passed in function call. Why cant we have names also in 'arguments' variable?

Comment: The logic of a function should not be determined by the name of the original variable that was passed as a parameter. If it is so dependent on the originating variable, it looks to me like you should be passing additional parameters (with the information contained in the variable name) or have multiple functions altogether

Comment: @ Alvaro Montoro: Like I said, I need something to be done inside the functionn body only as every part of application is not in my control and I need at least a workaround right now

Comment: I can't echo @AlvaroMontoro's comment enough. If the names of the variables used by the caller change the function logic, you've just plain built it wrong. Horrifically wrong. Can you explain more about why you need to change the logic of the function based on the caller's variable names? That's the real problem to solve.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt: commented above

Comment: Why on earth would you imagine that a function would be able to detect what variables were used as parameters calling it? The parameters might not even be variables--they might be expressions. They what would you expect to print out?

Comment: @ShishirArora the way I see the problem (I may be wrong) you need to make changes not only in the body of the function, but also where the function is called. Unless the parameters that you pass have additional information (e.g. they are objects and have properties with the same info that you'd get from the variable name), I'd say what you want to do is nearly impossible... and I don't like throwing the word impossible around much

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: I know its not possible but javascript is such a flexible language that apart from the arguments object, it also provides the caller's environment in the scope('this'). Cant we use that?

Comment: @ShishirArora as far as I know, it won't be that useful. Question: can you change the parameters and/or the way the function is called?

Comment: @ AlvaroMontoro I can change the formal parameters in function definition but I cannot change the actual arguments in the function call or in the way its called.

Comment: Can you infer the function logic based on the values of the arguments? Do the numbers of arguments change? I think what people are trying to explain is that you are asking the wrong question. It seems you have a case where other parts of your application are calling this one function, but they expect this function to behave in different ways. This is screaming "change the other parts". I would analyze the code you have access to, or talk to the other teams to see if you can identify a pattern in the values being passed to your function, or the numbers of arguments.

Comment: I know people want to answer this question by changing it. I wont change my question, but  I can remove it if u all want that. If I had to change other parts of my application, I would not have asked this question in first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need that because the names also contain some information which I need in my function logic
>
> if i call func(a,b,c,d) then there is one flow if logic in func and if I call it with func(l,m,n,d) then the logic flow in func algorithm changes and accordingly the output will change too

There is something profoundly wrong with your understanding of JS, or your conception of your problem, or more likely both.

**Functions cannot know, and do not know, and must not know, and have no reason to need to know, what variables, values, or expressions were used in calling them.**

I have no idea if this will solve your problem, whatever it is, but consider doing the following instead:

```
func({a,b,c,d});
```

The `{a,b,c,d}` format creates an object with keys of `a` etc. whose values are the variable `a`. This is ES6 syntax. In ES5:

```
func({a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d});
```

Then, in your function, you can look at the keys in the object passed in as a parameter.

Comment: I am not looking for any perfect answer but the answer should solve the problem as much as it can. Passing objects or functions in the call will not happen in my case.

Comment: Then there is no answer, other than writing your own JS parser and implementation which manages the information you want. `this` has nothing to do within anything.