# JavaScript file parser to get methods and arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any parser for JavaScript file? 
I want to get/grep the argument list for a parameter.

As an example:

```
function a(){
}

function b(){
}

function body_4(chk, ctx) {
        ctx = ctx.shiftBlocks(blocks);
        //WANT TO GET THE #3rd parameter JSON object. 
        return chk.partial("components/TextInput/textInput", ctx, {
            "className": "firstName",
            "name": "firstName",
            "id": "firstName",
            "placeholder": "Please enter first name",
            "maxlength": "30",
            "required": "required",
            "errorMessage": "Please enter a valid first name",
            "value": body_5
        }).partial("components/TextInput/textInput", ctx, {
            "className": "lastName",
            "name": "lastName",
            "id": "lastName",
            "placeholder": "Please enter last name",
            "maxlength": "30",
            "required": "required",
            "errorMessage": "Please enter a valid last name",
            "value": body_6
        });
    }
```

WANT TO GET THE #3rd parameter JSON object where the 1st argument is:`"components/TextInput/textInput"`

Any Node module or any kind of javaScript Library would do..

The Output I am looking for is:

```
            {
                "className": "lastName",
                "name": "lastName",
                "id": "lastName",
                "placeholder": "Please enter last name",
                "maxlength": "30",
                "required": "required",
                "errorMessage": "Please enter a valid last name",
                "value": body_6
            }
```

Comment: You can try to use http://esprima.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try using RegEx. Something like:
(}).partial("components/TextInput/textInput", ctx, )({)([\s\S]+)(});)+
For testing regex check out [this](http://regexr.com/) site

the third group will be ([\s\S]+) the content of the the Object(JSON)/

You can also check this: 
[How to get function parameter names/values dynamically from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically-from-javascript)