# How to check arguments of an injected function?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection

How does a function, *fA*, that accepts a function, *fB*, as an argument verify *fB's* required arguments?

```
var some_object = { fA : function( fB )
                           { 
                             // This function will send one parameter, a string, into fB ...
                             //   ... no matter how fB is designed.
                             // Therefore a mechanism is needed to check fB's arguments.

                             console.log( "Aa : " + fB            ) ;       
                             console.log( "Ab : " + fB.arguments  ) ;          
                             console.log( "Ac : " + fB.toString() ) ;         
                             console.log( "Ad : " + typeof fB     ) ;         


                             var lva_args = fB.toString().split(")")[0].split("(")[1].trim().split(/\s*,\s*/)                             ;

                             console.log( "Ae : " + lva_args)  ; 
                             // argn,arga,args .... 
                             //   ... but these are just their names, 
                             //       and do NOT indicate their type  

                             console.log( "Af : " + typeof lva_args[ 0 ] + " , " + typeof lva_args[ 1 ] + " , " + typeof lva_args[ 2 ]   ) ; 
                             // string , string , string 

                             var processed = fB.apply( null , [ 'abc' ] ) ;
                             return processed ;
                           }
                  } ;

var the_result = some_object.fA( function my_any_function( argn  , arga , args )  
                                   { console.log( "Ba : " + typeof argn + " , " + typeof arga + " , " + typeof args ) ; 
                                     // string , undefined , undefined 

                                     return argn * 10  ; 
                                     // argn should be a number !!!
                                     // .fA()  and  my_any_function 
                                     //    ... are NOT in agreement
                                   }
                                ) ;   

console.log( "Z : " +  the_result ) ; // --> NaN ... but it could've been worse.
```

I included the `.toString()' option because I understand that angular converts injected functions into strings and then parses through them to find the arguments, but that must be really messy (thanks @georgeawg).

My [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3z5ZXfC310l5ekAeAY2j?p=preview).

Comment: it can't see arguments (against laws of physics), but it could see the formal parameters using `toString()`. look for a Function.name polyfill or just `fn.toString().split(")")[0].split("(")[1].trim().split(/\s*,\s*/)` to get an array of formals.

Answer (score 0):

I think Angular's method you mention in your question (parsing through the string representation of the function) is the only way to test the parameters of *fB*.  Just for reference, [here's the source for how Angular does this parsing](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/auto/injector.js#L65).

In your case, however, even this method isn't guaranteed to ensure that *fB* accepts the parameters you expect - it's possible this method might generate false negatives.  For example, according to its signature, this function takes no arguments:

```js
function functionWithNoArguments() {
  document.writeln(arguments[0]);
}

functionWithNoArguments('Hello, world!');
```

See also: [How to get function parameter names/values dynamically from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1007981/1063392)

Comment: I don't believe though that fA can test them ... it can get their 'names' ... but beyond that I don't think it can check their expected types ... ... I believe that if this `toString()` procedure is the only way, then it is up to _fB_ to check how fA treats it, and fB handles error-checking .... but whoa that seems wrong ...