# How do I access store state in React Redux?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am just making a simple app to learn async with redux. I have gotten everything working, now I just want to display the actual state onto the web-page. Now, how do I actually access the store's state in the render method?

Here is my code (everything is in one page because I'm just learning):

```
const initialState = {
        fetching: false,
        fetched: false,
        items: [],
        error: null
    }

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "REQUEST_PENDING": {
            return {...state, fetching: true};
        }
        case "REQUEST_FULFILLED": {
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                fetched: true,
                items: action.payload
            }
        }
        case "REQUEST_REJECTED": {
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}   
        }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};

const middleware = applyMiddleware(promise(), thunk, logger());
const store = createStore(reducer, middleware);

store.dispatch({
    type: "REQUEST",
    payload: fetch('http://localhost:8000/list').then((res)=>res.json())
});

store.dispatch({
    type: "REQUEST",
    payload: fetch('http://localhost:8000/list').then((res)=>res.json())
});

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
            { this.props.items.map((item) => <p> {item.title} </p> )}
        </div>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

So, in the render method of the state I want to list out all the `item.title` from the store.

Thanks

Comment: You are almost there.  You need to create a store connected component using the `react-redux` library.  I highly recommend you polish your understanding of redux with the free course by the author: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: You do `store.getState()` to actually read the state from your store. http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#getState

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I don't fully understand redux and this tutorial will help me out a lot.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You should create separate component, which will be listening to state changes and updating on every state change:

```
import store from '../reducers/store';

class Items extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };

    store.subscribe(() => {
      // When state will be updated(in our case, when items will be fetched), 
      // we will update local component state and force component to rerender 
      // with new data.

      this.setState({
        items: store.getState().items;
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.items.map((item) => <p> {item.title} </p> )}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

render(<Items />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: @1ven how to we get `store` variable defined here?

Comment: @BangDao we can assume, that we are importing it from external file. `store` variable - it is redux store instance.

Comment: @BangDao You should include the `store` import for clarity.

Comment: ReferenceError Can't find variable: store

Comment: @PeteAlvin you need to have a redux store variable defined in your scope.

Comment: Aren't we supposed to access the reducer for that file instead of the entire store? Just access the itemsReducer instead to limit the state scope provided to items class

Comment: `import store from '../reducers/store';` .   and `store.js` would contain `const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware,promise)(createStore);
export default createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);`

Comment: @1ven or you could have added that line to your answer, much better than assuming

Comment: @Annjawn can you provide a answer?  'applyMiddleware' is not defined  no-undef
    'thunkMiddleware' is not defined  no-undef
    'promise' is not defined          no-undef
    'createStore' is not defined      no-undef
   'reducers' is not defined         no-undef

Answer (score 56):

Import `connect` from `react-redux` and use it to connect the component with the state `connect(mapStates,mapDispatch)(component)`

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally you need to map the states to the props to access them with `this.props`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    title: state.title
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Only the states that you map will be accessible via  `props`

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36214059/4040563

For further reading : https://medium.com/@atomarranger/redux-mapstatetoprops-and-mapdispatchtoprops-shorthand-67d6cd78f132

Comment: NOTE: This way, the props won't be accessible without invoking the action (defined in `mapDispatchToProps`). If you are attempting to obtain what's already in the store without dispatching another fetch cycle then you would have to use either `subscribe` or `getState` on the `store`.

Answer (score 25):

All of the answers are from pre-hook era. You should use useSelector-hook to get the state from redux.

In your redux-reducer file or somewhere where you can import it easily:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export function useEmployees() {
  return useSelector((state) => state.employees)
}
```

In your application code:

```
const { employees } = useEmployees()
```

More information on redux-hooks: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks to accomplish this goal.

Comment: Will this hook listen to the changes in the store? Will it update the local variable and re-render the component every time the store is changed?

Comment: @IbrahimFarooq, yes, it does. It functions like a passed prop.

Comment: Why we need another hook over useSelector()? 
```const employees = useSelector( state => state.employees)```

Comment: @Yogi, you can totally use it without the extra-hook. I personally prefer to keep the Redux-specific useSelector only under Redux-folders. Secondary reason is that I find the useEmployees to be more expressive

Comment: @IlmariKumpula Thank you for the explanation! Thats good format to keep useSelector call functions under redux folder.

Comment: @IlmariKumpula you don't need to do anything in your reducer, you can simply `import {useSelector} from react-redux` in any functional component and access the state directly: `const employees = useSelector((state) => state.employees)`.

Comment: Very good idea, you might add that this solution only works in `Component` context. Otherwise we must use `store.getState()`.

Answer (score 21):

You need to use [`Store.getState()`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate) to get current state of your Store.

For more information about `getState()` watch [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-store-methods-getstate-dispatch-and-subscribe?course=getting-started-with-redux) short video.

Comment: So do I just change `this.props.items` to `store.getState().items`? When I did it, it's not outputting the `item.title`.

Comment: @Parkicism looks like you do not did initial rendering for your component. I highly recommend you to watch this course: https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: @Parkicism this not displaying items, because when app is rendering first time, response from server is not received yet, you need to subscribe to store, to update component each time store changes.

Comment: I have `let store = createStore(todoApp);` in `index.js` and I want to access the `store` inside `App.js` - What is the way of it ?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_redux.Store.getState')

Comment: @PeteAlvin Store is not a member of Redux variable. You should use store received from createStore(), like in this example: https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#example

Comment: @semanser I'm trying to access the store in a view that's in an external .js file (not in the main App.js file where I call createStore()).  So, I'm guessing I need to put the store in a "global object" that is shared across all views?

Comment: @semanser I thought the purpose of <Provider store={store}> was to be able to access the store from views, but I can't find any examples of how to actually retrieve it from a view in a separate file.

Comment: I agree, in my case useSelector was  fetching stale data as compared to store.getState() . state changes were dispatched and called from the same component.

Comment: Is there something like Store.getState() but for React Context? Without any devtools, I'm looking for a simple command I can use in the browser console directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You want to do more than just `getState`.  You want to react to changes in the store.

If you aren't using react-redux, you can do this:

```
function rerender() {
    const state = store.getState();
    render(
        <div>
            { state.items.map((item) => <p> {item.title} </p> )}
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('app')
    );
}

// subscribe to store
store.subscribe(rerender);

// do initial render
rerender();

// dispatch more actions and view will update
```

But better is to use react-redux.  In this case you use the Provider like you mentioned, but then use [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) to connect your component to the store.

Comment: The op asked specifically for React-Redux. Why provide solution for something other than the request?

Comment: ReferenceError Can't find variable: store

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do some high-powered debugging, you can subscribe to every change of the state and pause the app to see what's going on in detail as follows.

store.js

```
store.subscribe( () => {
  console.log('state\n', store.getState());
  debugger;
});
```

Place that in the file where you do `createStore`.

To copy the `state` object from the console to the clipboard, follow these steps:

1. Right-click an object in Chrome's console and select Store as Global Variable from the context menu. It will return something like temp1 as the variable name.
2. Chrome also has a `copy()` method, so `copy(temp1)` in the console should copy that object to your clipboard.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25140576

https://scottwhittaker.net/chrome-devtools/2016/02/29/chrome-devtools-copy-object.html

You can view the object in a json viewer like this one: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

You can compare two json objects here: http://www.jsondiff.com/

Comment: good article too https://coderwall.com/p/pafnew/redux-middleware-logger

Answer (score 1):

**HACK SOLUTION**: Example from my **REAL project**! Save Redux store objects to external JSON file.

**STEP-1** import useStore first from react-redux and then getState() function is used to access store state.

**STEP-2** area is the name of my slice in Redux store and areaName is state in that slice.

**STEP-3** FiletoSave variable is used to export JSON file with data from store.

```
import { useStore } from "react-redux";

const exportJsonFileFromStore = () => {

const store = useStore();
const FileSaver = require('file-saver');    
    
function exportData() {
   
    const filename = 'filter_settings';

    let prepareObject = {       // It is used to make a JSON object 
      areaName:store.getState().area.areaName  ,   
    }
    const fileToSave = new Blob([JSON.stringify(prepareObject)], {
        type: 'application/json'
    });
    // this will save file
    FileSaver.saveAs(fileToSave, filename);
}

return (
  
        <button onClick={(event: any) => exportData()}>Click me to download!</button>
   
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
import { ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';
var store  = useContext(ReactReduxContext).store.getState();

console.log(store);
```

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store#using-reactreduxcontext-directly