# How to change this state with react-redux

Tags: react-redux

Hi i am learning react with redux and i don't know how to put table inside items.

[redux dev tools picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exr1E.png)

This is my reducer:

```
  case FETCH_CART_PRODUCTS:
  return {
    ...state ,
    items: action.payload
  }
  case PURCHASE:
  return {
    ...state,
    orders: action.payload
  };
  case FETCH_ORDERS:
  return {
    ...state,
    orders: action.payload
  }
  case TABLE_NUMBER:
  return {
    ...state,
    table: action.payload
  }
default:
  return state;
```

}
}

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 0):

State is always accessible via store.getState() function.

check below answer for more info.

[How do I access store state in React Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332912/how-do-i-access-store-state-in-react-redux)

Comment: In particular, you want to focus on the connect HOC in the guide above to connect your component to the state with mapStateToProps