# console.log(this.props.store) returning undefined in my create react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, create-react-app

I created a create react app and included redux with card lists and a searchbox that displayed the filtered results, the app was working before I added redux but now it isn't returning any results. When I console.log(this.props.store) it is returning undefined. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this. My files are as below:

constants.js

`export const CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD = 'CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD';`

actions.js

```
import {CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD} from './constants.js';

export const setSearchField = (text) => ({
       type: CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
       payload: text
})
```

reducer.js

```
import {CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD} from './constants.js';

const intialState = {
    searchField: ''
}

export const searchTeacher = (state=intialState, action={}) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD:
                return Object.assign({}, state, { searchField: action.payload });
        default: 
                return state;
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import App from './App.js'; //Our main parent component
import {searchTeacher} from './reducer.js';
import 'tachyons';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore(searchTeacher)

ReactDOM.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
         <App />
     </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') );

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import CardList from './CardList.js';
import {teacher} from './teacher.js';
import Searchbox from './searchbox.js';
import ErrorBoundry from './ErrorBoundry';
import Scroll from './Scroll.js';
import './App.css';
import {setSearchField} from './actions.js';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        searchField: state.searchField
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

    return {
        onSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value))
    }
}

class App extends Component {

    constructor(){   
         super()
         this.state = {
         teacher: teacher, //teacher: [],  
        }
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.store);
        const { searchField, onSearchchange } = this.props; 
        const filteredteacher= teacher.filter( 
            teacher =>{
                         return teacher.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()); 
                      });
        return(
            <div className="tc">  
              <h1 className="f1"> Faculty Members ! </h1>
              <Searchbox searchChange={onSearchchange} /> 
              <Scroll>
                <ErrorBoundry>
                 <CardList teacher={filteredteacher} />
                </ErrorBoundry> 
              </Scroll>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: markerikson, Waheed Akhtar, fadzb thank so much for your reply I did try out your methods and after some debuggings, I found it wasn't the store that was causing the problem, there was a typo, in mapDispatchToProps it is defined as onSearchChange and in render() I used it as onSearchchange. I can't believe it was something so silly that caused so much problem. Thank you once again though, your replies helped me understand the problem much better.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any `props.store`, because none of your code is passing down a prop named `store` to that component.

Components that have been wrapped in `connect` get props from three sources, combined:

- Props passed from the parent component
- Props returned from `mapState`
- Props returned from `mapDispatch`

In this case, `mapState` is returning `{searchField}`, and `mapDispatch` is returning `{onSearchChange}`, and there's no props from the parent.  So, the combined props are `{searchField, onSearchChange}`.

As a side note, you should use [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) instead of writing it as a function:

```js
const mapDispatch = {onSearchChange: setSearchField};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get two props from redux according to your code,

1. `this.props.searchField`
2. `this.props.onSearchChange`

connect function of react-redux used to connect react and redux.

`mapDispatch is used to dispatch your actions which hold the payload(Second argument of connect function)`

`mapState is used to get the state of your properties(First argument of connect function)`

So in your code, there is not any prop named store, Store is a global redux state which you can get with this method `Store.getState()` but here is store is redux store which you are passing here `const store = createStore(searchTeacher)` in your `index.js` file, This will show whole state of the redux store.

here is how you can get the state of your store.

[How do I access store state in React Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332912/how-do-i-access-store-state-in-react-redux)

You will dispatch an action named `onSearchChange` like below in your on change method.

```
this.props.onSearchChange(e)
```

and redux will return you a value of this after storing in reducer with the name of `this.props.searchField`.

Answer (score 0):

this.props.store would only be accessible if it was passed down from a parent component (which you are not doing here)

You create your store in index.js but you are not exposing an interface to it.

```
const store = createStore(searchTeacher);
```

You can expose these functions from your index.js file to reference the store:

```
export const getStore = () => store;
export const getState = () => {  return store.getState(); };
```

Then from anywhere else (although not good practice):

```
import { getStore, getState } from 'index.js';
```