# Redux: accessing dictionary as state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, redux, react-redux

I have implemented a shopping cart using Redux, I have used a dictionary as state object (product id being the key and quantity in cart being the value). Here is how my `cart.js` looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export const AddItemToCart = (productID) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADDITEMTOCART',
        productID
    }
}
export const DeleteItemFromCart = (productID) => {
    return {
        type: 'DELETEITEMFROMCART',
        productID
    }
}
export const Counter = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADDITEMTOCART':
            console.log(action);
            return {
              ...state,
              [action.productID]: ( state[action.productID] || 0 ) + 1
            }
        case 'DELETEITEMFROMCART':
            return {
              ...state,
              [action.productID]: ( state[action.productID] || 1 ) - 1
            }
    }
  }
```

I'm adding an item from `App.js` like this:

```
return products.map(products =>
      <div key={products.ProductID}>
        <h2>{products.ProductName}</h2>
        <h2>{products.ProductDescription}</h2>
        <h2>{products.ProductQuantity} units available</h2>
        
        <button onClick={() => { store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
      store.dispatch(AddItemToCart(products.ProductID));}}>Add to cart</button>
        </div>
```

Everything is working just fine but the problem is, I can't render the contents of the cart for user to see. I have tried:

```
function ShowCartContents() {
  var items = Object.keys(store.getState()).map(function(key){
    return store.getState()[key];
});
  return (
    <div>
        <h2>{items}</h2>
      </div>
  );
}
```

This function throws exception when called:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Clearly the store itself is not null or undefined, because the change of state is successfully printed to the browser console. So, how would I access all the values in dictionary without keys? And how would I access one specific value by key? Any advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ``connect`` your component where this function resides ``ShowCartContents()``? You can import ``connect`` from ``react-redux``

Comment: @BattleHawk Oh I didn't... let me see about that.

Comment: Could someone show an example of how to use connect()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332912/how-do-i-access-store-state-in-react-redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Counter` reducer has no `default` case, so your `state` will be `undefined` on the first render.

That's the source of your error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

You need to return the existing state when neither action matches.  Every reducer needs a `default` case because they will be called with actions like the `{type: '@@redux/INIT'}` action which is used to initialize the store.

```
default:
  return state;
```

---

You are trying to access the store directly with `store.subscribe()`, `store.getState()` and `store.dispatch()`.  **This is not the correct way to interact with a Redux store in React.**  You should use the `react-redux` package.

---

You want to wrap your entire app in a `Provider` component that provides the `store` instance.  Something like this:

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import App from "./components/App";
import store from "./store";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

---

In your components, use the hook `useSelector` to select values from the state and `useDispatch` to access the `dispatch` function.  (You can also use the `connect` higher-order component, but the hooks are preferred).

I'm not sure if this reducer is your entire state or if you are using `combineReducers` and have multiple reducers like `cart`, `products`, etc.  This selector is assuming that it's the entire state.

```
function ShowCartContents() {
  const productIds = useSelector(state => Object.keys(state))
  
  return (
    <div>
        <h2>Ids In Cart: {productIds.join(", ")}</h2>
      </div>
  );
}
```

```
function ProductsList({ products }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div key={product.ProductID}>
          <h2>{product.ProductName}</h2>
          <h2>{product.ProductDescription}</h2>
          <h2>{product.ProductQuantity} units available</h2>

          <button onClick={() => dispatch(AddItemToCart(product.ProductID))}>
            Add to cart
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```