# Redux #subscribe vs. #mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is the purpose of using `subscribe` in code like `store.subscribe(render)`? Doesn't using `mapStateToProps` and `connect` already cause the connected component to re-render each time the store's state changes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting the Redux.js page:

> Technically you could write the container components by hand using store.subscribe(). We don't advise you to do this because React Redux makes many performance optimizations that are hard to do by hand. For this reason, rather than write container components, we will generate them using the connect() function provided by React Redux,

If you're already using react with redux, you might as well use their package, since it is already optimized.

Also referencing a previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36214059/3938413

Answer (score 5):

The examples showing `store.subscribe(render)` are using small code snippets showing you the basic way to hook redux into react.

`store.subscribe` comes from the `redux` package.
`connect` comes from the `react-redux` package and is not a part of redux itself.

The `react-redux` package uses `store.subscribe` to hook itself into the redux dispatch cycle. You can then access the redux store by using the `connect` component enhancer.

Third party libs (or middleware for example) can hook into the store lifecycle via `store.subscribe`.