# Change route on async action finish in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm using React, Redux and react-router. I have a button "Add member" that opens a "new member" form, using react-router.

In the "app container", I have this:

```
<Switch>
    //other stuff
    <Route exact path='/addmember' component={ NewMemberForm }/>
</Switch>
```

and the button:

```
<Button label='Add member' onClick={ _ => this.props.history.push('/addmember')} />
```

Form is opened properly. `NewMemberForm` component has two buttons: `Add` and `Cancel`. `Cancel` button, basically, does `this.props.history.push('/')` to go back to the home page.

When user clicks `Add`, form data is read and an async action is dispatched:

```
//add member using the api and set the generated ID
export const requestAddMember = member => dispatch => {
  return api.addMember(member)
    .then(memberId => dispatch(
      addMember(Object.assign(member, { id: memberId }))));
};

const addMember = member => {
  return { type: ADD_MEMBER, member };
};
```

I need to go back to the home page (`this.props.history.push('/')`), when `ADD_MEMBER` action is dispatched, i.e. when the new member is actually added.

When do I have to handle that action and call `this.props.history.push('/')`? Should it be in the async action creator before dispatch `ADD_MEMBER`?

```
//add member using the api and set the generated ID
export const requestAddMember = member => dispatch => {
  return api.addMember(member)
    .then(memberId => dispatch( // should it be here before this dispatching?
      addMember(Object.assign(member, { id: memberId }))));
};
```

Comment: You can put it in the `.then()`. At the end of the day your route might change before your reducer updates the state. But once the state updates your component should rerender with the updated sate, so it shouldn't really matter. If you're worried about routing before state is updated consider waiting to route until the value you expect has been added to state.

Comment: Why not subscribe to members in `NewMemberForm`? When the new one's added, redirect home.

Comment: @Galupuf how can I wait to that? How should I check it?

Comment: @Alex How can I subscribe to the array?

Comment: @Héctor With `react-redux`, it's fairly straightforward; you can use the [`connect` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212860/subscribe-to-single-property-change-in-store-in-redux#36214059).

Comment: Yes, but what am I supposed to do? Maybe in `mapStateToProps` check if new item is present and if so redirect home? How I know is it added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution.

**history.js**

```
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
export default createHistory()
```

and in the action creator:

**actions.js**

```
import history from './history';

...

//add member using the api and set the generated ID
export const requestAddMember = member => dispatch => {
  return api.addMember(member)
    .then(memberId => {
        history.push('/'); //this line
        dispatch(addMember(Object.assign(member, { id: memberId })))
    });
};
```