# Best way to inject a function using InversifyJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

There's an [official recipe](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/recipes.md#injecting-dependencies-into-a-function) to inject a function using [InversifyJS](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS). Basically, we define a helper function that will return a curried version of a given function `func` with all its dependencies resolved using `container.get(...)`:

```
import { container } from "./inversify.config"

function bindDependencies(func, dependencies) {
    let injections = dependencies.map((dependency) => {
        return container.get(dependency);
    });

    return func.bind(func, ...injections);
}

export { bindDependencies };
```

And we use it like this:

```
import { bindDependencies } from "./utils/bindDependencies";
import { TYPES } from "./constants/types";

function testFunc(something, somethingElse) {
    console.log(`Injected! ${something}`);
    console.log(`Injected! ${somethingElse}`);
}

testFunc = bindDependencies(testFunc, [TYPES.something, TYPES.somethingElse]);

export { testFunc };
```

I'd like to inject the function automatically, without explicitly provide it's dependencies to `bindDependencies`, maybe based on the function's parameters names. Something like this:

```
import { default as express, Router } from 'express';

import { bindDependencies } from '../injector/injector.utils';

import { AuthenticationMiddleware } from './authentication/authentication.middleware';
import { UsersMiddleware } from './users/users.middleware';

import { ENDPOINTS } from '../../../../common/endpoints/endpoints.constants';


function getRouter(
    authenticationMiddleware: AuthenticationMiddleware,
    usersMiddleware: UsersMiddleware,
): express.Router {
    const router: express.Router = Router();

    const requireAnonymity: express.Handler = authenticationMiddleware.requireAnonymity.bind(authenticationMiddleware);
    const requireAuthentication: express.Handler = authenticationMiddleware.requireAuthentication.bind(authenticationMiddleware);

    router.route(ENDPOINTS.AUTHENTICATION)
        .put(requireAnonymity, authenticationMiddleware.login.bind(authenticationMiddleware))
        .delete(requireAuthentication, authenticationMiddleware.logout.bind(authenticationMiddleware));

    router.route(ENDPOINTS.USER)
        .put(requireAnonymity, usersMiddleware.register.bind(usersMiddleware))
        .post(requireAuthentication, usersMiddleware.update.bind(usersMiddleware))
        .delete(requireAuthentication, usersMiddleware.remove.bind(usersMiddleware));

    return router;
}

const router: express.Router = invoke(getRouter);

export { router as Router };
```

Note in this case I just want to call the injected function once and get its return value, which is what I'm exporting, so maybe there's a better way to do this without wrapping the code in a function, but I though using `container.get(...)` directly outside of my composition root was not a good idea, as the dependencies for this module would not be clear and may be spread across all its lines. Also, exporting that function would simplify the tests.

Going back to my issue, my `invoke` function looks like this:

```
function invoke<T>(fn: Function): T {
    const paramNames: string[] = getParamNames(fn);

    return fn.apply(null, paramNames.map((paramName: string)
        => container.get( (<any>container).map[paramName.toUpperCase()] ))) as T;
}
```

For `getParamNames` I use one of the solutions proposed here: [How to get function parameter names/values dynamically from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically-from-javascript)

`(<any>container).map` is an object I create in my `inversify.config.ts` after creating my container, which links a string representation of all my dependencies' keys and the real key, regardless of its type (in this case, just `symbol` or `Function`):

```
const container: Container = new Container();

container.bind<FooClass>(FooClass).toSelf();

...

const map: ObjectOf<any> = {};

(<any>container)._bindingDictionary._map
    .forEach((value: any, key: Function | symbol) => {
        map[(typeof key === 'symbol'
            ? Symbol.keyFor(key) : key.name).toUpperCase()] = key;
    });

(<any>container).map = map;
```

Anyone knows if there's a better way to do this or if there's any important reason not to do it?

Comment: @ower-reloaded Maybe you can throw some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem about using the function argument names is the potential issues when compressing the code:

```
function test(foo, bar) {
    console.log(foo, bar);
}
```

Becomes:

```
function test(a,b){console.log(a,b)}
```

**Because you are working in a Node.js app, you are probably not using compression so this should not be a problem for you**.

I think your solution is a good temporal solution. If you check the [TypeScript Roapmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#future), in the "Future" section we can see:

> - Decorators for function expressions/arrow functions

This means that in the future InversifyJS will allow you to do the following:

> Note: Assuming that `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `UsersMiddleware` are **classes**.

```
@injectable()
function getRouter(
    authenticationMiddleware: AuthenticationMiddleware,
    usersMiddleware: UsersMiddleware,
): express.Router {
    const router: express.Router = Router();

    const requireAnonymity: express.Handler = authenticationMiddleware.requireAnonymity.bind(authenticationMiddleware);
    const requireAuthentication: express.Handler = authenticationMiddleware.requireAuthentication.bind(authenticationMiddleware);

    router.route(ENDPOINTS.AUTHENTICATION)
        .put(requireAnonymity, authenticationMiddleware.login.bind(authenticationMiddleware))
        .delete(requireAuthentication, authenticationMiddleware.logout.bind(authenticationMiddleware));

    router.route(ENDPOINTS.USER)
        .put(requireAnonymity, usersMiddleware.register.bind(usersMiddleware))
        .post(requireAuthentication, usersMiddleware.update.bind(usersMiddleware))
        .delete(requireAuthentication, usersMiddleware.remove.bind(usersMiddleware));

    return router;
}
```

or the following:

> Note: Assuming that `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `UsersMiddleware` are **interfaces**.

```
@injectable()
function getRouter(
    @inject("AuthenticationMiddleware") authenticationMiddleware: AuthenticationMiddleware,
    @inject("UsersMiddleware") usersMiddleware: UsersMiddleware,
): express.Router {
    const router: express.Router = Router();

    const requireAnonymity: express.Handler = authenticationMiddleware.requireAnonymity.bind(authenticationMiddleware);
    const requireAuthentication: express.Handler = authenticationMiddleware.requireAuthentication.bind(authenticationMiddleware);

    router.route(ENDPOINTS.AUTHENTICATION)
        .put(requireAnonymity, authenticationMiddleware.login.bind(authenticationMiddleware))
        .delete(requireAuthentication, authenticationMiddleware.logout.bind(authenticationMiddleware));

    router.route(ENDPOINTS.USER)
        .put(requireAnonymity, usersMiddleware.register.bind(usersMiddleware))
        .post(requireAuthentication, usersMiddleware.update.bind(usersMiddleware))
        .delete(requireAuthentication, usersMiddleware.remove.bind(usersMiddleware));

    return router;
}
```