# How to get the literal name of a variable?

Tags: javascript

So I am really tired of writing out `console.log` all of the time so I wrote a small function called `clog` to pass the parameters into a `console.log`.

I want to optimize this, however, that whenever I pass in a variable it should print the variable name and then the value:

```
clog(i)     //=> i: 0
clog(myVar) //=>myVar: [1,2,3]
```

How would I do this?

Here's what I have currently:

```
const clog = (...args) => console.log(...args)
```

Comment: Are you not using an IDE with autocomplete?

Comment: @tic I am but I want something even lazier. I don't want to have to type out `clog('i',i)` every single time. Way too much typing.

Comment: What’s your IDE? I’m pretty sure u can use a shortcut autocomplete which will place a double caret for u to write your variable name as string and as actual variable at once. I use such approach on vscode

Comment: You can also just call console.log with as many arguments as you want `console.log(i, myVar, anotherVar)` They don't all have to be on a new line

Comment: @tic that is not what they were asking about. They want those `i` and `myVar` names as part of the log output. So just use object notation, and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the variable you want to log in {},  like this:

```js
const clog = (...args) => console.log(...args)

const i = 'hello'

const myVar = {a: 2}

clog(i)     //=> i: 0

clog(myVar) //=>myVar: [1,2,3]

clog ({i})
 //{
 // "i": "hello"
 //}
```

see
[How to console log the name of a variable/function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087850/how-to-console-log-the-name-of-a-variable-function).

You could also go further and try this:

```html
<script>
    const clog = (...args) => {
        args.forEach(arg => {
            if (typeof arg === 'object')
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arg)) {
                    console.log(key, value)
                } else {
                    // dev forgot to wrap input to clog in a {}, so just log normally
                    // or change this to throw an error, enforcing all calls to clog must be an object
                    console.log(arg)
            }
        })
    }

    const i = 'hello'
    clog(i)
    console.log({i})

    const j = 'bye'
    clog({ i }, { j })

    const myVar = { a: 2 }
    clog({ myVar })
    console.log({myVar})

    const otherVar = { b: 2, c: { d: 7, e: 'wow' } }
    clog({ otherVar })

    clog({ myVar }, { otherVar })

    clog() // does not error if no args

    clog({}) // handles empty object input
</script>
```

To see the improvement you will need to open this up in a browser and see how the clog statement "unwrapped" the object, presenting a arguably clearer log line, but still retaining the capability to inspect deeper into the object being logged in the browser.

Compare the output for:

```
clog({ myVar })
```

[image]

And

```
console.log({myVar})
```

[image]

See which you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Use object notation, taking advantage of shorthand property names:

Wherever you changed your code to call `clog(...)`, change it back to `console.log` calls, and just pass in your variable in an object wrapper.

```
console.log({ i }); // yields { i: 0 }
console.log({ myVar }); // yields { myVar: [1,2,3] }
```

Want to log lots of stuff? Same deal:

```
console.log({ i, myVar }); // yields { i: 0, myVar: [1,2,3] }
```

Want to keep your `clog` function? Still the same deal: wrap anything you need the varname for in object notation first, then throw it into your custom logging function.

Comment: const clog = (...args) => console.log({...args})

Comment: No? That alone does not preserve the input variable names, so if you call `clog(a,b)` what you log does _not_ have the varnames `a` and `b` in it anymore, which is what they were asking about how to achieve. Start by using object notation, and _then_ do your logging however you need it to happen.