# How to log both variable and its name?

Tags: javascript

I find myself typing this repeatedly for debugging in my code. Is there a way to create a function for this?

```
var abc = 1
console.log("abc = "+abc);

var xyz = 2;
console.log("xyz = "+xyz);
```

I would like to create a function like this:

```
logVar = function(input){
  console.log(input.name()+" = "+input);
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

logVar(abc) should return **"abc = 1"**

logVar(xyz) should return **"xyz = 2"**

Comment: Is there any functional reason to do this other than just manually typing the variable name as a string?

Comment: Not possible. JS doesn't hold the "name of the variable" value anywhere with the variable. What you are passing is just the value of it. What you probably need is a debugger, rather than having less code to type in order to debug stuff.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087922/4925008

Comment: Similar question asked and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52598270/11465123

Comment: how about this workaround: `console.log({ abc, xyz });`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to enclose you var in a object to get its name as a key:

```js
var myVar = 'John Doe';

console.log({myVar}); // result {"myVar": "John Doe"}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create an object from your variable which you pass into `logVar`.Then, in your function, you can use [`Object.entires`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the name of the variable and the value of the variable.

See example below:

```js
var logVar = function (input) {
    var [[name, val]] = Object.entries(input);
    console.log(name, "=", val);
}

var abc = 1;
var xyz = 2;

logVar({abc}); // abc = 1
logVar({xyz}); // xyz = 2
```

Comment: What's the pratical difference with console.log({abc}) ?

Comment: @AntonioBuelli no practical difference. I'm just giving the output that the OP wanted, whereas `console.log({abc})` gives the details, just not in OP's desired format

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not a proper solution, you can loop over the window object, but you can get other identifiers as well which hold the same value as the passed in argument. This only works in global scope & not while in function scope.

```
var ident = "wowowowow";
console.log(getIdentifierName(ident));

function getIdentifierName(identifier) {
  for (var prop in window) {
    if (window[prop] === identifier) {
      console.log(identifier);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not all var are in window scope, mate

Comment: What if the variable not global or not attached to `window`?

Comment: That's what I said, that this is not a proper solution @MosèRaguzzini

Comment: It won't work @VLAZ

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```js
var abc = 1;
logVar = function(input) {
  console.log(input);
}
logVar({
  abc
});
```

The output should be something like : { abc: 1 }

Comment: what is the purpose of `logVar`? It's just doing `console.log` but limits it to a single argument.

Comment: its what he asked for. I do not know why he want's it like that.

Comment: Well, he also asked for the output to have a `=` but yours doesn't. If you're deviating in the implementation in one place, it seems strange to keep up to it in another.

Comment: this solution has the same effects as `console.log({abc})`