# Function parameter: Get name of undefined variable

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

If one of my functions get an `undefined` parameter passed, I want to get the name of the variable outside the function so I can better troubleshoot the `undefined` variables. I.e.:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById("myTable").dataset.tablename;
//myVar: undefined

testVar(myVar);

testVar(param1) {
  if (!param1) console.log(passed parameter ??? undefined);
}

//??? shall be "myVar"
```

Comment: That's just not possible. The expression in the calling environment is evaluated, and all the target function gets is the value. You could generate an error and dump a stack trace out to the console.

Comment: Use `typescript` to find such mistakes while programming. Thats much better then finding such stuff at runtime. And that pseudocode is ugly, just saying...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the thing you want to achieve is possible. You can look at the stack trace at debug time, but I will give you further information and ideas here:

1. You could have a development policy in your team to name outside variables the same way as the parameters are at functions whenever possible. If you do so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically) post will become useful.
2. You might introduce a policy to pass objects to functions, like `{name: 'John', age: 3}` and then you will know the keys.
3. You could create a `Trackable` prototype which would have a `key` and a `value`, like this:

`function Trackable(name, value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}`

and pass trackables to functions when their names will be needed, thus you will call `testVar(new Trackable('myVar', myVar))` and inside you will check param1.value against undefined and if it is undefined, then use the name in your report.