# Python dir or Object.keys() equivalent to inspect Node callback function arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that in JS, i can use `Object.keys(object)` to inspect the various properties of an object, but I am wondering if there is a similar to find out what arguments a JS callback function expects.

For instance, i know the the callback function for `request.get` expects `error`, `response` and `body` respectively, but how can i find this out by using something similar to pythons `dir` or JS's `Object.keys()`

I understand that an IDE can help with this, but I am trying to find out if it is possible to do this using just JS

Comment: Check the function's `length` for the number, or if you *have* to, call `toString()` on it to see their names (hopefully it's not minified). But any script that has to do this is quite a code smell.

Comment: @CertainPerformance would you have an example on how to do this using the `request.get` example?

Comment: good IDE's intellisence will tell you what arguments are. What is your specific use case?

Comment: @securisec there are some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically -- most seem like cautionary tales to me.

Comment: Yes, this is helpful, but how would I use any of those ideas on a **callback** function? I tried using the `acorn` example, but i get back an empty array. Here is the code `request.get(url, function a(){ console.log(  acorn.parse(a).body[0].params.map(x => x.name) ); })`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flow, TypeScript, or Tern, your editor/IDE can most likely provide that info for you. If you're not, you can use `someFunction.toString()`.