# How to destructure an object into parameter names

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have many functions defined elsewhere that look like this

```
export function foo(bar1, bar2, bar3, ...) {
  // does stuff
}
```

In the module I am working on I am passed both the function above and an object containing the parameters like this:

```
// params = {
//   bar1: bar1Value,
//   bar2: bar2Value,
//   bar3: bar3Value,
//   ...
// }
function myFunc(foo, params) {

}
```

I need to call func with the params in the correct order. It is an object not an array so I can't rely on the property order, I need to match up the params to the signature of the function. Is this possible?

Edit to add: There are hundreds of functions that can be passed in, I am trying to avoid refactoring them all, but it seems that it is impossible to look up the parameter names directly. However I've [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically#9924463) which shows it can be done by breaking down the function as a string.

Comment: actually it is not possible, because the parameter names are not readable.

Comment: are the properties of params called bar1, bar2 etc (or do you know their names)? If so, its possible

Comment: As @NinaScholz said, you can’t do this dynamically. You may want to use an object as an argument though: `function foo({ bar1, bar2, bar3 }) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties of an object (like "params") either like 
`params.bar1` or like `params["bar1"]` and you can get the names of the properties by using `Object.keys(params)`, if thats what your asking for.

See also https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys