# How can I get properties of a type as an array in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following type:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(
        private one: string, 
        private two: string, 
        private three: string) {
    }
}
```

How can I have an array whose values are the type's properties?

e.g. I need to be able to get an array as:

> ['One', 'Two', 'Three']

Note I need to have the properties extracted from a type and not an instance otherwise I could simply use `Object.keys(instanceOfFoo)`.

Comment: where is the array defined? Is each one an array or is there a different array property? How do you want to use this?

Comment: There is no array, I want to be able to produce an array based on the keys (fields) defined on the type.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @MaYaN Could you please explain your post in more detail with example? I am not able to understand it currently.

Comment: I don't think you can get it from the types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Reflect.construct()` to get the keys, then use `Object.keys()` to convert that to an array.

**Note:** if the key doesn't have a default it won't be generated as you can see with `four`.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.one = ''
    this.two = ''
    this.three = ''
    this.four
  }
}

console.log(Object.keys(Reflect.construct(Foo, [])))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!, Actually I don't need to initialize the fields either, it works beautifully.

Comment: Note that this isn't compatible with IE if you are targeting IE browsers.

Comment: Isn't it basically same as `new` though?

Comment: This looks like a typescript version of C# reflection

Comment: @NimaHakimi yes it is. " It is equivalent to calling new target(...args). ", the return is an instance of the target. There is no difference in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you just one to list the field's name from a class you can use the following:

```
let fields = Object.keys(myObj) as Array<MyClass>;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate **`const a = new Foo();`** and access using **`Object.keys`**

```
class Foo {
    constructor(
        private one: string, 
        private two: string, 
        private three: string) {
    }
}

const a = new Foo();
console.log(Object.keys(a)); // ["prop"]
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zsr7qxL4/1/)**

EDIT:
If you want to get from the type it is not possible since types won't be available once the code is compiled.

Comment: As I explained in the post, I need to get this from the type and not an instance.

Comment: You cannot create from a type since all the types are gone once compiled.

Comment: I know how I can make a type based on another type's keys e.g. `const myType: keyof Foo` which would be: `one | two | three` but I need to turn that into an array of `['one', 'two', 'three']`

Comment: whats the problem of instantiating it?

Answer (score 1):

Since the  code above will be transpiled to following js code:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo(one, two, three) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
        this.three = three;
    }
    return Foo;
}());
```

I'd first extract the constructor using `const c = Foo.prototype.constructor` and the get the name of arguments from that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically) thread shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Scan the Object.keys(Foo.prototype)

Comment: `Object.keys(Foo.prototype)` returns an empty array.

Comment: You need to initialize the values with a default, such as `null`. otherwise they won't show.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn It is still empty.

Comment: use `new` as well `console.log(Object.keys(new Foo))`