# Call Typescript methods with named parameters from decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm fairly new into typescript, coming from java and still trying to get into typescript. I'm trying to write a small lib for a rest service with express, using typescripts decorator.

```
@rest() //Not yet sure if i really need this
class RestCall{

    @get("/path")
    doSomething(id: number, name: string){
        console.log(id+": "+name);
    }
}
```

So, I want to call this method, whenever express gets a call on "/path". I also want to call the method with it's parameters from the get request.
The only problem I have is calling this method with the parameters in the right order cause it should also work with this:

```
@rest() //Not yet sure if i really need this
class AnotherRestCall{

    @get("/path")
    doSomething(name: string, id: number){ //Not the same order as above
        console.log(id+": "+name);
    }
}
```

In the second class, parameters are in an other order.
I tried around with the descriptor and it's value but i can not find a way of getting a list (if possible) of parameters in their order.

```
function get(path: string){
    return (target: Object, propertyKey: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>): any =>{

    }
}
```

Worst of all is that i don't have a clue on what i should actually search for. In a way i want named parameters from typescript, but not really since it's executed on runtime so there is only javascript left.

Maybe i missed some basic things..

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Unfortunately types are lost in the process but you can, at least, get the names: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924463/1207195. What I'd suggest is also to try another approach: what about `doSomething(params: {name: string, id: number})`? BTW Isn't something missing? You can't/shouldn't have ordinal parameters without a proper definition as in `get("/path/{name}/{id}")`...

Comment: Names are the only thing i need so losing types is fine.
Object as parameter is not bad. I'll probably do that if i dont find another way.
Yep, parameters are not in path yet. I'm just trying to dynamically call functions yet.