# Get all the arguments specified in the constructor but not those inherited from the parent classes in javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

I'm looking for a way to get all the arguments of a javascript object. Only those specified in the constructor, not those inherited from the parent classes. I have found a lot of examples and tutorial online, including this website but none of them filtered only the argument specifically defined in a class. I couldn't find any way to extract it myself. If for instance, I have a class defined like this:

```
class Camera extends Node{
        constructor(type="Camera", name="Camera", position=[0,0,0], target=[0,0,0], up=[0, 1, 0]) {
        super(type, name);
        ...
```

I want to make sure I only get:  "type", "name", "position", "target" and "up". I tried many variations at this point but one of the last ones was:

```
printClassArguments (object) {
            for (const key in object) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
                    const value = object[key];
                    console.log("found argument "+key)
                }
            }
    }
```

Unfortunately that output:

```
scene.printClassArguments (scene.cameras[0])
 found property _type
 found property _name
 found property _components
 found property _id
 found property cameraType
 found property _target
 found property _up
 found property _fov
 found property _near
 found property _far
 found property _aspect
 found property _projectionMatrix
 found property _viewMatrix
 found property transform
 found property _defaultViewMatrix
 found property _defaultTarget
 found property _sensitivity
```

Which is not what I want. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An object doesn't know how its properties have been created. There is nothing you can do except parse the string representation of the constructor to extract parameter names. But that's not foolproof.

Comment: ^ Here is what Felix is talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1007981/9867451