# Javascript: Pass function with arguments as parameter and get this args

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write some js function's validation.

Idea: I have checking function, passing to it checked function object, here make sure that all right (or not). I don't want to pass arguments separately, only function object.
How can i reach this?

For now i forced to be content with two parameters for checking function - func obj and func arguments

That is what i want:

```
function checkFunction(func) {
    console.log(func.name);
    console.log(func.arguments);
    // validate something
}

function checkedFunction(a, b, c) {
    checkFunction(checkedFunction...);
    // do something
}
```

That is what i have now:

```
function checkFunction(func, args) {
    console.log(func.name);
    console.log(args);
    // validate something
}

function checkedFunction(a, b, c) {
    checkFunction(checkedFunction, arguments);
    // do something;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible - the current arguments the function was called with must be passed along directly somehow (like passing a parameter of `arguments` or with argument rest syntax), they're not a property of the function or anything.

Comment: The name of the function is misleading: you're not checking a function, you're checking a function call.

Comment: You can get function arguments names. Read this [How to get function parameter names/values dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically)

Comment: @Alexander not my issue, unfortunately. I need arguments for validation (for example not equals to null, etc).

Comment: I think you are talking about callback function?