# Get the name of the argument from inside the function?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get the name of the variable passed in as an argument from inside of the function, if a variable has been passed in?

```
function foo(bar){
  // how to get the string `obj`?
}

const obj = {a:1};

foo(obj)
```

Comment: What would you expect from the call `foo(3)`? Or `foo(1+2+3)`?  Or `foo(sum([1,2,3]))`?

Comment: what you really want I mean 1. are you really want to know about passed parameter name . 2. or you want to use its value

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi OP's code seems to specifiy that they want the string `\`obj\``, *not* its value.

Comment: @EternalHour I don't believe that's a duplicate. It fetches the names of the function *parameters*, not the passed-in *arguments*.

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate, he wants the name of the variable in the outer scope, which is not possible. The corner cases provided by @ScottHunter reveal a fundamental problem with the goal proposed by the OP which were likely not considered when asking the question.

Comment: I would assume this is impossible, given that the `function foo(bar)` is never passed the string `"obj"`; as far as I'm aware, it's passed solely the value that the variable represents.

Comment: For the record: It was proposed that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically is a duplicate, but that "*fetches the names of the function parameters, not the passed-in arguments.*" as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @ScottHunter the question was to get the name of a variable. in your examples, `foo(3)` and `foo(1+2+3)` and `foo(sum([1,2,3]))`; `3` is not a variable, nor is `1+2+3` nor the other...

Comment: @Gunther: That was the point: there might not be a variable to get the name of, and `foo` can't tell the difference.