# Javascript - split values inside parentheses

Tags: javascript, split

I am trying to split the following string:

> delete(value1,value2);

I want to get the values and save them in a array:

```
var values = [value1,value2]
```

Comment: Feels like an XY problem here. Why do you have a function declaration that is a string? And you can’t access the live values of the arguments in a string since they’re most likely only available at runtime.

Comment: @Terry I have updated it to not cause confusion. The important thing is to get the values of the parenthesis.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get function parameter names/values dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string using split function

```
var str = "delete(value1,value2)";
var stringArray = str.split("(");
var values=stringArray[1].split(",");
```

use Replace method to finally delte ")" from second string in array

```
values[1]=values[1].replace(")","");
```

Comment: A very smart solution. thanks and please put the "S" of the lowercase variable

Comment: @python38291 thanks for the prompt for correction. It is made now.

Answer (score 1):

A regex would do the trick:

```
/\((.*)\)/g.exec('delete(value1,value2);')[1].split(',')
```

This captures anything between parentheses, which you can then split again.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;


function getParamNames(fnStr) {
  var fnStr = fnStr.replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES);
  if(result === null)
     result = [];
  return result;
}


var str = "delete(value1,value2)";
getParamNames(str);
```