# Inversify cannot inject class with dependencies

Tags: typescript, inversion-of-control, create-react-app, inversifyjs

I started a new typescript project based an old project of mime (which started as plain javascript) and I can't get any non-trivial injection working. I know about nothing about babel configuration (because of staring with create-react-app). I tried [the recommended compilerOptions](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS#installation) and it didn't work either..... my setup may be a mess, but that's how it evolved.

Feel free to get the whole project from [github](https://github.com/Maaartinus/inversify-problem) (get it and run `npm install && npm start`) or continue reading.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Container } from 'inversify';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { injectable } from 'inversify';

@injectable()
export class Simple {
}

@injectable()
export class Composed {
    simple: Simple;

    // ERROR: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'
    // constructor(@inject simple: Simple) {
    //  this.simple = simple;
    // }

    // Error: Missing required @inject or @multiInject annotation in: argument 0 in class Composed.
    constructor(simple: Simple) {
        this.simple = simple;
    }
}

const container = new Container();
container.bind(Simple).toSelf();
container.bind(Composed).toSelf();
console.log(container.get(Composed));

function Main() {
    return <div>
        {JSON.stringify(container.get(Composed))}
    </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### package.json

```
{
    "name": "inversify-problem",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.8",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
        "array.prototype.flatmap": "^1.2.3",
        "customize-cra": "^0.9.1",
        "deep-equal": "^2.0.1",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "inversify": "^5.0.1",
        "json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.1",
        "mobx": "^5.15.4",
        "mobx-decorators": "^6.0.1",
        "mobx-react": "^6.1.8",
        "mobx-state-tree": "^3.15.0",
        "notistack": "^0.9.9",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
        "react-app-rewire-mobx": "^1.0.9",
        "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.5",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
        "shallowequal": "^1.1.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
        "ts-enum-util": "^4.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.7",
        "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
        "@types/deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
        "@types/json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.32",
        "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
        "@types/node": "^13.9.8",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.29",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
        "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^0.1.2",
        "tslint-etc": "^1.10.1",
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-app-rewired start",
        "build": "react-app-rewired build",
        "test": "react-app-rewired test",
        "eslint": "eslint --fix $(find src -name '*.ts' -o  -name '*.tsx')",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app",
        "parserOptions": {
            "ecmaFeatures": {
                "legacyDecorators": true
            }
        }
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
    ]
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable",
            "esnext",
            "es6",
            "webworker",
            "es2015.collection",
            "es2015.iterable",
            "es2019"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node",
            "reflect-metadata"
        ],
        "allowJs": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "incremental": false,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "noEmit": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/index.tsx",
        "src/mg/extras.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

#### config-overrides.js

```
const {
    override,
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
);
```

## Debugging

I tried to debug the problem, but found not much out. There are no metadata, no attempt is made to parse Function.prototype.toString() like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924463/581205). There's something wrong with my configuration, but that thing is pretty opaque to me.

Comment: Updated my answer with a complete solution, that allows constructor (parameter) injection and all. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You are struggling because the react babel config does not allow decorators, so what you can do is:

```sh
$ npm run eject
$ npm install react-scripts # if you use an older npm installation then you need to add --save
$ npm install -D @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators 
$ npm install -D babel-plugin-parameter-decorator
```

Your `package.json` is now expanded with a lot of options, find the `babel` section and change it as follows:

```
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        "babel-plugin-parameter-decorator"
      ]
    ],
    "presets": [
      // ...
      ["@babel/preset-typescript", { "onlyRemoveTypeImports": true }]
    ]
  }
```

now you can at least use field injection as follows:

```js
// ...
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
// ...

@injectable()
class Composed {
    private readonly simple: Simple;

    public constructor(@inject(Simple) simple: Simple) {
        this.simple = simple;
    }
}

//...
```

The solution is based on this:

- https://www.robinwieruch.de/create-react-app-mobx-decorators (enable decorators)
- https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/issues/261 (fixing the missing file with `react-scripts`)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-parameter-decorator

For more info on why decorators isn't supported:

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/214
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/411

Comment: Somehow, it didn't work for me, see https://github.com/Maaartinus/inversify-problem/commit/32c5f90cb33fad2a28817968f55e5c97dfb7568d. I also don't understand why the class-based approach (no constructor params annotations) doesn't work. I use annotations with mobx in my real-live project where I encountered this problem.

Comment: Wondering if I forgot something in my answer, you're right, I can confirm this on your code too :/ You can do the injection on the field though, so it's likely the `babel-plugin-parameter-decorator` that doesn't get registered correctly :/

Comment: I'm a bit pressed on time, so I can't dive further into it for now. However, this should work at least:

```typescript
@injectable()
export class Composed {
 @inject(Simple) private readonly simple!: Simple;
}
```

it's not as nice, but it should keep you going. I updated the config a bit in the answer to reflect best practice and fix the accidental change from preset `react-app` to `react-native`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same solution as [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61391162/4536543) but instead of using `package.json`, I used `config-overrides.js`:

```js
const {
  override,
  addDecoratorsLegacy,
  addBabelPlugin,
} = require("customize-cra");

module.exports = override(
  addDecoratorsLegacy(),
  addBabelPlugin("babel-plugin-parameter-decorator")
);
```

To be honest, I didn't like this solution so I didn't post it...

Comment: This solution might have one advantage. I suspect (without checking) that the `addDecoratorsLegacy`-wrapper has been made to account for the different ways of adding the decorators. My solution only works with Babel 7 and above, there's a different plugin for earlier Babel versions