# How to add a proptype of a setState method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm creating a reusable component for a project that I have. 
This component has a user and a setUser as props like the example bellow.

```
const UserComponent = ({ user, setUser }) => {

     const calcHandler = useCallback(() => {
        setUser(prevUser => {
             // ...some calculation
             return userCopy;
         });
     }, [setUser]);

     return (
         <div>
             ... some content
         </div>
     );
 };
```

As you can see this component has a method to calculate some operations called calcHandler, and there is only one dependency.

This is the proptype validation:

```
 UserComponent.propTypes = {
    user: PropTypes.shape({
        // some props
    }).isRequired,
    setUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

However, for the prop setUser it is mandatory to be like a setState method (one from the useState hook). Because I can get the previeous value from it and prevent to add other dependency to the useCallback.

```
setUser(prevUser => //... some calculation);
```

I need to improve the validation of the prop setUser. It isn't just a function.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: What makes a function returned from `useState` different than any other function? I'm not sure there's anything distinguishing there.

Comment: I can pass a function as arg and get the previous state value from it

Comment: From what I can tell, `prop-types` doesn't support function argument validation.

Answer (score 0):

> However, for the prop setUser it is mandatory to be like a setState
>   method (one from the useState hook). Because I can get the previeous
>   value from it and prevent to add other dependency to the useCallback.

That sounds like you are looking for [PropTypes.shape](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) but for a `function`

Unfortunately there isn't such thing and the only alternative is **custom validator**

Additionally you have to find a way to get [function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically) and its return value as its required for validation.

```js
var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
var ARGUMENT_NAMES = /([^\s,]+)/g;
function getParamNames(func) {
  var fnStr = func.toString().replace(STRIP_COMMENTS, '');
  var result = fnStr.slice(fnStr.indexOf('(')+1, fnStr.indexOf(')')).match(ARGUMENT_NAMES);
  if(result === null)
     result = [];
  return result;
}

TaskManagerFollowUp.propTypes = {
  setUser: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    const prop = props[propName];

    if(!getParamNames(prop).length) { // doesnt take any param
      throw new Error('invalid function propType')
    }

  }
}
```