# Testing Asynchronous functions - JEST

Tags: javascript, jestjs, asynccallback

**Code-1:**

```js
describe("testing server functionalities", () => {
    
    // test case
    it("server handles a function", () => {
        request('some link', (error, response, body) => {
            var expected = "1410";
            expect(expected).to.be.equal(body);
        })
    })

});
```

**Code-2:**

```js
describe("testing server functionalities", () => {
    
    // test case
    it("server handles a function", (done) => {
        request('some link', (error, response, body) => {
            var expected = "1410";
            expect(expected).to.be.equal(body);
            done();
        })
    })

});
```

So here in `Code-1`, we have the problem that the test exits before checking whether the `value` meets the `expected value` because the request call is *asynchornous*.

To handle this problem, I found a way where the introduced argument `done` as in the `Code-2` makes the test function wait for the `done()` function to get called which finally makes the test function work properly.

But I am not sure how the `Code-2` works and why does the test function wait for the `done`.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean _why_ does it wait for done? Because that's the _whole point_ of it, so you can inform the test runner when you consider the test complete. But I'd encourage the use of one of the other options: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Comment: @jonrsharpe so you are saying it's to do with the internal logic of Jest framework and nothing to do with the concept of callback right?

Comment: I've no idea what distinction you're trying to draw there. It's the internal logic of the framework, implemented using a callback.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically) you can see how we could know which arguments does function expects.

And this is the simplest one.

Also it is possible to get this parameters by parsing JS-file to Abstract Syntactic Tree(AST).

And then it is easliy possible to create different logic.

Let's imagine how it could look (**abstractly**):

```
// Some testing framework code
const shouldWaitUntilDone = testcase.hasDoneCallback();

if (shouldWaitUntilDone) {
  // Callback will run when done() is called
  testcase.run(() => { testcase.runMatchers(); }) 
} else {
  testcase.run().runMatchers();
}
```