# Get the names of function parameters from outside of the function

Tags: javascript

I want to know if it possible to get the names (not the values) of the function parameters from outside of a function, either with a native JavaScript function/method or something custom.

```
// function parameters cat, dog, bird
function foo(cat, dog, bird) {};

// now access these names from outside the function, something like (pseudocode)
foo.getFunctionParameters();
```

or

```
getFunctionParameters(foo);
```

Which would log

> ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']

The reason:
I have an object that has a `values` functions. These functions have different function parameters. I must loop through this `Object` and execute the `function`. I do not want to pass a `key` with each `Object` that contains the `function`, telling me which `function parameter` to pass (via an `if...else`). I'd simply create an `Object` with my possible `function parameters` and the use the actual `function parameters` to access the needed `values`.

```
const someArray = [
    {
        foo: [
            {
                function: (cat, dog) => {...},
                otherKeys: otherValues,
            },
            {
                function: (apple, orange) => {...},
                otherKeys: otherValues,
            },
            {
                function: (cat, apple) => {...},
                otherKeys: otherValues,
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```

Then I'd simply construct an object with the possible function parameters

```
const possibleFuncParams = {
    cat: 'Sweet',
    dog: 'More a cat person',
    apple: 'I like',
    orange: 'not so much',
    ...
}
```

And then use the `function paramaters` coming back from `getFunctionParameters()` to access the `object` (something like this):

```
const keys = getFunctionParameters();
possibleFuncParams[keys[0]];
possibleFuncParams[keys[1]];
```

What I do not want to do is

```
const someArray = [
    {
        foo: [
            {
                function: (cat, dog) => {...},
                otherKeys: otherValues,
                keyToSelectFuncParam: 'animals'
            },
            {
                function: (apple, orange) => {...},
                otherKeys: otherValues,
                keyToSelectFuncParam: 'fruits'
            },
            {
                function: (cat, dog) => {...},
                otherKeys: otherValues,
                keyToSelectFuncParam: 'mixed'
            },
            ...
        ],
        ...
    }
]
```

And then

```
if(keyToSelectFuncParam === 'animals') {
    foo.functio('Sweet', 'More a cat person');
}
```

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, what would the intended use case be for this?

Comment: I doubt it's possible.  This sounds like an XY Problem.  Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @Etheryte I edited my Question to reflect more on this

Comment: @David I edited my Question to reflect more on this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I got this by googling... try it

```js
// JavaScript program to get the function
// name/values dynamically
function getParams(func) {

  // String representaation of the function code
  var str = func.toString();

  // Remove comments of the form /* ... */
  // Removing comments of the form //
  // Remove body of the function { ... }
  // removing '=>' if func is arrow function
  str = str.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//g, '')
    .replace(/\/\/(.)*/g, '')
    .replace(/{[\s\S]*}/, '')
    .replace(/=>/g, '')
    .trim();

  // Start parameter names after first '('
  var start = str.indexOf("(") + 1;

  // End parameter names is just before last ')'
  var end = str.length - 1;

  var result = str.substring(start, end).split(", ");

  var params = [];

  result.forEach(element => {

    // Removing any default value
    element = element.replace(/=[\s\S]*/g, '').trim();

    if (element.length > 0)
      params.push(element);
  });

  return params;
}

// Test sample functions
var fun1 = function(a) {};

function fun2(a = 5 * 6 / 3, // Comment
  b) {};

var fun3 = (a,
  /*
   */
  b, //comment
  c) => /** */ {};

console.log(`List of parameters of ${fun1.name}:`, getParams(fun1));
console.log(`List of parameters of ${fun2.name}:`, getParams(fun2));
console.log(`List of parameters of ${fun3.name}:`, getParams(fun3));
```