# How to convert function argument to string in JS?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a function argument name into string.

```js
const newFn = 'something';
const transformVarName = (variable) => {
  return Object.keys({variable});
  };
  
  console.log(transformVarName(newFn)) // Should return 'newFn', not 'variable'
```

Comment: Function should return the name of the variable that I use as argument in this function.

Comment: That is not possible. A variable name is not a string. Related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007981/how-to-get-function-parameter-names-values-dynamically/32108558#32108558

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return Object.keys({newFn})[0]
```