# Get variable name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, attributes

How can I get the name of a variable?

Let's say I have an empty variable:

```
var myvariable;
```

How can I get the variable name so that this:

```
alert(this_is_what_i_am_looking_for);
```

will display:

```
myvariable
```

**EDIT:**

Maybe I am overcomplicating things. My real problem is that I have this two variables:

```
var firstVariable;
var secondVariable;
```

And I want to create a third variable that literally has this name:

```
var firstVariablesecondVariable;
```

EDIT2:

Thank for the answers, too much information, I have to look at them thoroughly.

This is what I have:

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

var i = 0;
var q = 0;

$('div').each(function() {
    var qi;
    i++;
});​
```

So I want to create three varaibles: var 00;var 01;var 02;
Then I will load more divs with ajax and do:

```
q++;
i=0;
```

so when I apply the each function the second time I have three more variables: var 10;var 11;var 12;

Comment: How you expect to know it? what paramters you want to search with? a value?

Comment: what is "this_is_what_i_am_looking_for". you have to give us something to work with that in some way relates to "myvariable"

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense as it's written.  Perhaps you could expand on the example.  How can that `alert()` not know the name?

Comment: you have to clarify exactly how you plan on knowing to use variable1 and variable2 to make variable1variable2, as opposed to variable4 or variable9

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve by creating a variable called `firstVariablesecondVariable`?

Comment: check out this tread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009911/javascript-get-argument-value-and-name-of-passed-variable

Comment: Sorry if I sound confusing. I edited again. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: @Alvaro, after looking in your edits I would say you need a object hash to store the states of the class (or maybe a clousure, depending of the context).

Answer (score 3):

Variables names are identifiers and you cannot "ask" for an identifier what its name is. What you can do is create a new variable with the *contents* of the identifier, like this:

```
 var var1 = "variable1";
 var var2 = "variable2";

 // this will create an property/variable "variable1variable2" 
 // on the global namespace.
 window[var1 + var2] = "xyz";

 var content = variable1variable2; // content = xyz;
```

Comment: this creates variables in a global context

Comment: @andresdescalzo, yes, this is only possible for the global context, for any other context you must prepend the context like "obj.variable1variable2", otherwise it will not work.

Comment: ok, I understand, I just seemed right clear it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use a hashtable to map name to values. Finally the name barFoo with value barFooTest is added in the hashtable.

```
var o = { bar: 'barTest' };
o.foo = 'fooTest';

var prevKey = '';
for(key in o)
{   
    prevKey = prevKey + '' + key ;
    alert(key + ': ' + o[key]);
}

o[prevKey] = "barFooTest";
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible, what you could do is work with a json object:

```
var myvars = {
   'firstVariable': 1,
   'secondVariable': 2,
   'firstVariablesecondVariable': function() { return this['firstVariable'] + this['secondVariable']; }
};


console.log(myvars['firstVariable'+'secondVariable']());
​
```

[run code](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/4ZRfM/)

**For edit**

```
var elements = [];
var myformat = function(n) { return (String(n).length == 1 ? '0' : '') + n; }
$('div').each(function(i, el) {
    elements.push(myformat(i));
});

console.log(elements);
​
// response ["00", "01", "02"]
```

[run code](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/b6tSA/)

**Edit II**

but if you want set values to variables, you can try this:

```
var elements = {}; // <- object
var myformat = function(n) {
    return (String(n).length == 1 ? '0' : '') + n;
}
$('div').each(function(i, el) {
    elements[myformat(i)] = el;
});

console.log(elements);​

Object
00: HTMLDivElement
01: HTMLDivElement
02: HTMLDivElement
```

[run code](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/zp8f4/)