# Validating arguments in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I have a function with a bunch of arguments, and I just want to check if any of them are falsy (empty, undefined, null, etc.).

One option is obvious to just check every argument individually, but it's pretty repetitive:

```
if not arg1
  response.send 400, 'Missing argument arg1'
if not arg2
  response.send 400, 'Missing argument arg2'
```

I can simplify that a bit with this, but I still have to list out every every argument and argument name:

```
for key, value of { 'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2 }
  if not value
    response.send 400, "Missing argument #{key}"
```

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
for key, value of arguments
  if not value
    response.send 400, "Missing argument #{key}"
```

But `arguments` is more like an array. Is there a way to get the arguments as an object, or get the argument names as an array? Am I going about this this wrong way?

What is a good way of validating a bunch of arguments without repeating myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write an check function that parses the parameter names from the string representation of your function (there is really no other way)

```
check = ()->
    f = "" + arguments.callee.caller
    r = /function \((.*)\)/
    regres = r.exec(f)
    pnames = regres[1].split(",")
    params = (pn.trim() for pn in pnames)
    for index in [0...arguments.length]
        if arguments[index] == null || arguments[index] == undefined
            console.log "argument: #{params[index]} is null"

handleRequest = (x, y, z)->
    #give all your params in the correct order to the check function
    check(x, y, z)

handleRequest(1, 2, "lala")
handleRequest(1, 2)
```

Now the fact that this is somehow possible shouldn't mean that you should do it. This **solution** is at best brittle and will create confusion if you change parameter position. Some would probably claim its evil - me included ;-)

I'd rather advise you that you change your API design.

From your **response.send** I would assume that you are in an web environment? Why dont you simply use the params hash that the framework you are using is handling to you? Most frameworks will do exactly this.

Another possibility would be to define default values for your parameter so that **received** parameters are always well defined?

```
handleRequest = (x, y = "somevalue", z = "anothervalue")->
```

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely way too evil to actually use, but it's an entertaining solution. Sending the parameter object may work though, thanks for the idea.

Comment: +1 This sounds like a problem that would be solved by "reflection" facilities in compiled languages (Java, Go…) and the string representation of a function is the thing that most closely resembles reflection in JS.

Comment: The last lines of the check function can be refactored to: `console.log "..." unless arguments[index]?`

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no clear way of achieving what you want, but a nasty way of doing this (based on similar threads for javascript, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009911/javascript-get-argument-value-and-name-of-passed-variable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914968/inspect-the-names-values-of-arguments-in-the-definition-execution-of-a-javascrip)), which may be error prone, is to parse the function itself, get the names of the arguments and make them an array:

```
fn = (a,b,c,d,e,f) ->
  fns = fn.toString()
  args = fns.slice(fns.indexOf('(')+1, fns.indexOf(')')).split(', ')
  for idx in [0...args.length]
    console.log 400, "Missing argument #{args[idx]}" unless arguments[idx]

fn('', null, 'arg1', undefined, 'arg2')

#Output:
#400 'Missing argument a'
#400 'Missing argument b'
#400 'Missing argument d'
#400 'Missing argument f'
```

Comment: That gives me output like, "Missing parameter 1". I want it say "Missing parameter arg1".

Comment: You mean something like `"Missing argument arg#{key}"` or `"Missing argument #{value}"`?

Comment: `"Missing argument #{key}"`. If the argument is named `x`, I want it to say "Missing argument x".

Comment: I think I understood what you are trying to do. Check my updated answer.